# Wrap a delegate in an IEqualityComparer

Tags: .net, linq, delegates

Several Linq.Enumerable functions take an `IEqualityComparer<T>`. Is there a convenient wrapper class that adapts a `delegate(T,T)=>bool` to implement `IEqualityComparer<T>`? It's easy enough to write one (if your ignore problems with defining a correct hashcode), but I'd like to know if there is an out-of-the-box solution.

Specifically, I want to do set operations on `Dictionary`s, using only the Keys to define membership (while retaining the values according to different rules).

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Ordinarily, I'd get this resolved by commenting @Sam on the answer (I've done some editing on the original post to clean it up a bit without altering the behavior.)

The following is my riff of [@Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/270203#270203), with a [IMNSHO] critical fix to the default hashing policy:-

```
class FuncEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    readonly Func<T, T, bool> _comparer;
    readonly Func<T, int> _hash;

    public FuncEqualityComparer( Func<T, T, bool> comparer )
        : this( comparer, t => 0 ) // NB Cannot assume anything about how e.g., t.GetHashCode() interacts with the comparer's behavior
    {
    }

    public FuncEqualityComparer( Func<T, T, bool> comparer, Func<T, int> hash )
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
        _hash = hash;
    }

    public bool Equals( T x, T y )
    {
        return _comparer( x, y );
    }

    public int GetHashCode( T obj )
    {
        return _hash( obj );
    }
}
```

Comment: As far as I'm concerned this is the **correct** answer. Any `IEqualityComparer<T>` that leaves `GetHashCode` out is just straight-up broken.

Comment: @Dan Tao: I might be missing something here, but the implementation that you gave in your answer delegates to T.GetHashCode, and this is not guaranteed to be a good hash code.  So are the other implementations more correct by providing an explicit hash function?  Also, why do you need the equality comparison at all, since if you had a hash function, you could test equality by comparing the hashes and not the object keys themselves?

Comment: @Joshua Frank: It's not valid to use hash equality to imply equality - only the inverse is true. In short, @Dan Tao is completely correct in what he says, and this answer is simply the application of this fact to a previously incomplete answer

Comment: @Ruben Bartelink: Thanks for clarifying.  But I still don't understand your hashing policy of t => 0.  If all objects always hash to the same thing (zero), then isn't that even *more* broken than using obj.GetHashCode, per @Dan Tao's point?  Why not always force the caller to provide a good hash function?

Comment: @Joshua Frank: Firstly, the chances are you're understanding things quite well. Nobody has found a hole in the computer science around hashing functions. The point was that @Sam's response used t=>t.GetHashCode() as the hashing function. The only time that makes sense is if every single time Equals<T> returns true, the underlying values are guaranteed to return the same hash code. If this is not the case, the miscomputed hash code results in the search failing incorrectly.

Comment: Thus it is not reasonable to assume that an arbitrary algorithm in a Func its been supplied cannot possibly return true despite the hash codes being different. Your point that returning zero all the time is just not hashing is true. That's why there's an overload that takes the hashing Func for when the profiler tells us searches are not sufficiently efficient. The only point in all of this is that if you're going to have a default hashing algorithm, it should be one that works 100% of the time and doesnt have dangerous superficially correct behavior. And then we can work on the performance!

Comment: Anyway, I suspect that your point is "well thats not a good hashing function". If it is, my response is that you're correct, but quick and wrong doesnt beat slow and correct, esp. on an uber-trusted resource like SO :P If you actually feel that I'm incorrect in my correctness (not efficiency) claims, I suggest having another read of @Dan Tao's fantastic answer.

Comment: Re-reading your last comment, its clear you do understand it just fine. The word broken threw me. Broken describes the overload in @Sams' answer - couldnt possibly work. For me, the situation where someone wants to use an arbitrary Func just isnt the case where they are in a position or have a desire to come up with a correct associated hashing function **that is tailored to be guaranteed to include every subtlety of the inputs to outputs transformation involved in the Func**. Clearly there are order of magnitude efficiency differences with large data sets, but the profiler will show them.

Comment: @Ruben: Thanks for your valuable thoughts on this while I've been silent (read: lazy)! @Joshua: Here's the thing. The OP is asking about creating a custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation using *a single delegate* to use for the `Equals` method, right? There are actually two flavors of response here, which I think may have gotten you confused. One is that this idea *needs* to be supplemented with a custom `GetHashCode` function; that is, no `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation is truly functional without `Equals` **and** `GetHashCode`, for reasons explained already. (continued)

Comment: @Joshua: The *other* type of response being offered is that there's a similar but different way to approach this problem altogether: in many cases, rather than specify `Equals` and `GetHashCode` separately, it makes sense to simply supply a "key" which will be used to determine uniqueness instead. This is the concept behind methods such as `GroupBy` and `ToDictionary`: in this case, what is needed is simply a `Func<T, TKey>` to select the key, *which should be a type that already implements `Equals` and `GetHashCode` in a manner appropriate for use as a key*, e.g., `string`, `int`. (continued)

Comment: @Joshua: So really, these are two separate ideas. But the fact is that you're right to have spotted that something is missing: really, in my (original) answer, I should have suggested an overload for the `KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>` constructor that would accept an `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`. *This* would allow a developer to combine both flavors of response offered to this question. But in fact, I think the reasoning behind the `KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>` idea is that, if you're using it, you're going to use something reasonable for `TKey` like `string` or `int`, so you should be fine.

Comment: In other words, since you are using a **custom** comparer it has nothing to do with the object's **default** hash code related to the **default** comparer, thus you cannot use it.

Comment: @Peet Brits: Extremely well summarised - 2000 of my words in 20!

Comment: Loved the thread... any example of use especially with regards to hash?

Comment: @Kevin In what context ? Something like `Assert.Equal( expectedResult, actualResult, new FuncEqualityComparer<MyResult>( (x,y) => StringComparer.Equal( x.Name, y.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)))` ? It often makes more sense for a list (see the SequenceEqual extensions in @Sam's answer), or you might have a Factory Method with an Intention Revealing Name return your comparison. BTW these days when implementing Test Specific Equality, I generally reach for `Ploeh.SemanticComparison`'s `Likeness` stuff, e.g., http://stackoverflow.com/a/12819244/11635

Comment: @RubenBartelink: Sorry it took so long, but I've finally gotten around to reviewing the massive amount of answer/comment activity on this question, and decided that I agree with DanTao: this the correct answer.

Comment: @MarceloCantos: I'm honoured. Have to hand it to @DanTao though - he's covered stuff pretty completely. BTW since this answer, I've found I tend to mostly apply @orip's answer in practice i.e., a `.Select(x=>Tuple.Create(x...,x....)` and lean on the `Equals` (and of course the `GetHashCode`) of `Tuple`. And if anyone else has read down this far, I can highly recommend the last module of @Mark Seemann's excellent Advanced Unit Testing PluralSight course (and SemanticComparison library) with regard to thinking and impling Test Specific Equality which I guess is why people arrive at this question

Comment: Woha! So many comments! :P Anyhow... see my update of the implementation to .Net4.0 [as an answer to a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35520207/533837) - in short the comparer doesn't need to be generic anymore thanks to contravariance on the interface! (Which simplifies usage, adds the non-generic `IEqualityComparer` naturally and saves a tiny bit of memory.)

Comment: @AnorZaken Interesting; I wasn't aware of the other question (I've no idea if I've abused the above for reference equality on the fly (likely enough I guess!)

Comment: Even better, I'd say, instead of `t => 0`, write `t => { throw new NotImplementedException(); }`. I wouldn't want any unforeseen usage of this 'default hash function' to go unnoticed.

Comment: @JBSnorro Not so sure - that may technically be correct, however for many common cases people just want something quick and not wrong for a non-perf-critical scenario. Bottom line is that one either needs to read Dan's answer or use some mechanism leaning on Structural Equality (I rarely use end up using this construct on a permanent basis)

Answer (score 178):

## On the importance of `GetHashCode`

Others have already commented on the fact that any custom `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation **should really include a `GetHashCode` method**; but nobody's bothered to explain *why* in any detail.

Here's why. Your question specifically mentions the LINQ extension methods; nearly *all* of these rely on hash codes to work properly, because they utilize hash tables internally for efficiency.

Take [`Distinct`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx), for example. Consider the implications of this extension method if all it utilized were an `Equals` method. How do you determine whether an item's already been scanned in a sequence if you only have `Equals`? You enumerate over the entire collection of values you've already looked at and check for a match. This would result in `Distinct` using a worst-case O(N<sup>2</sup>) algorithm instead of an O(N) one!

Fortunately, this isn't the case. `Distinct` doesn't *just* use `Equals`; it uses `GetHashCode` as well. In fact, *it absolutely **does not** work properly without an `IEqualityComparer<T>` that supplies a proper `GetHashCode`*. Below is a contrived example illustrating this.

Say I have the following type:

```
class Value
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Number { get; private set; }

    public Value(string name, int number)
    {
        Name = name;
        Number = number;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}: {1}", Name, Number);
    }
}
```

Now say I have a `List<Value>` and I want to find all of the elements with a distinct name. This is a perfect use case for `Distinct` using a custom equality comparer. So let's use the `Comparer<T>` class from [Aku's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/98119#98119):

```
var comparer = new Comparer<Value>((x, y) => x.Name == y.Name);
```

Now, if we have a bunch of `Value` elements with the same `Name` property, they should all collapse into one value returned by `Distinct`, right? Let's see...

```
var values = new List<Value>();

var random = new Random();
for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
{
    values.Add("x", random.Next());
}

var distinct = values.Distinct(comparer);

foreach (Value x in distinct)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1346013431
x: 1388845717
x: 1576754134
x: 1104067189
x: 1144789201
x: 1862076501
x: 1573781440
x: 646797592
x: 655632802
x: 1206819377
```

Hmm, that didn't work, did it?

What about [`GroupBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534334.aspx)? Let's try that:

```
var grouped = values.GroupBy(x => x, comparer);

foreach (IGrouping<Value> g in grouped)
{
    Console.WriteLine("[KEY: '{0}']", g);
    foreach (Value x in g)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
    }
}
```

Output:

```
[KEY = 'x: 1346013431']
x: 1346013431
[KEY = 'x: 1388845717']
x: 1388845717
[KEY = 'x: 1576754134']
x: 1576754134
[KEY = 'x: 1104067189']
x: 1104067189
[KEY = 'x: 1144789201']
x: 1144789201
[KEY = 'x: 1862076501']
x: 1862076501
[KEY = 'x: 1573781440']
x: 1573781440
[KEY = 'x: 646797592']
x: 646797592
[KEY = 'x: 655632802']
x: 655632802
[KEY = 'x: 1206819377']
x: 1206819377
```

Again: didn't work.

If you think about it, it would make sense for `Distinct` to use a `HashSet<T>` (or equivalent) internally, and for `GroupBy` to use something like a `Dictionary<TKey, List<T>>` internally. Could this explain why these methods don't work? Let's try this:

```
var uniqueValues = new HashSet<Value>(values, comparer);

foreach (Value x in uniqueValues)
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
}
```

Output:

```
x: 1346013431
x: 1388845717
x: 1576754134
x: 1104067189
x: 1144789201
x: 1862076501
x: 1573781440
x: 646797592
x: 655632802
x: 1206819377
```

Yeah... starting to make sense?

Hopefully from these examples it's clear why including an appropriate `GetHashCode` in any `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation is so important.

---

## Original answer

Expanding on [orip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/1239337#1239337):

There are a couple of improvements that can be made here.

1. First, I'd take a `Func<T, TKey>` instead of `Func<T, object>`; this will prevent boxing of value type keys in the actual `keyExtractor` itself.
2. Second, I'd actually add a `where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>` constraint; this will prevent boxing in the `Equals` call (`object.Equals` takes an `object` parameter; you need an `IEquatable<TKey>` implementation to take a `TKey` parameter without boxing it). Clearly this may pose too severe a restriction, so you could make a base class without the constraint and a derived class with it.

Here's what the resulting code might look like:

```
public class KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    protected readonly Func<T, TKey> keyExtractor;

    public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, TKey> keyExtractor)
    {
        this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return this.keyExtractor(x).Equals(this.keyExtractor(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return this.keyExtractor(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}

public class StrictKeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey> : KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>
    where TKey : IEquatable<TKey>
{
    public StrictKeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, TKey> keyExtractor)
        : base(keyExtractor)
    { }

    public override bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        // This will use the overload that accepts a TKey parameter
        // instead of an object parameter.
        return this.keyExtractor(x).Equals(this.keyExtractor(y));
    }
}
```

Comment: Your `StrictKeyEqualityComparer.Equals` method appears to be the same as `KeyEqualityComparer.Equals`. Does the `TKey : IEquatable<TKey>` constraint make `TKey.Equals` work differently?

Comment: @JustinMorgan: Yes--in the first case, since `TKey` may be any arbitrary type, the compiler will use the virtual method `Object.Equals` which will require boxing of value type parameters, e.g., `int`. In the latter case, however, since `TKey` is constrained to implement `IEquatable<TKey>`, the `TKey.Equals` method will be used which will not require any boxing.

Comment: Very interesting, thanks for the info. I had no idea GetHashCode had these LINQ implications until seeing these answers. Great to know for future use.

Comment: It's sad that such beautiful constructs (as this answer) can't be typed without specifying the types (in methods as arguments). May be encapsulating the `new IEqualityComparer<>` expression in a static method would help it a bit.

Comment: @DanTao: Wouldn't it make sense to use `return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(keyExtractor(x), keyExtractor(y));` inside the Equals method? I mean, to handle null values and such?

Comment: @JohannesH: Probably! Would have eliminated the need for `StringKeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>` too.

Comment: +1 @DanTao: Belated thanks for a great exposition of why one should never ignore hash codes when defining equality in .Net.

Comment: Thank you for this good answer! I've changed it in my code and resolved the inheritance; i. e. made two separate classes, one `KeyEqualityComparer<T>` (where yours would be used as `<T, object>`) and another `KeyEqualityComparer<T, TKey>` which can now have the same name.

Answer (score 120):

When you want to customize equality checking, 99% of the time you're interested in defining the keys to compare by, not the comparison itself.

This could be an elegant solution (concept from Python's [list sort method](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Sortingbykeys)).

Usage:

```
var foo = new List<string> { "abc", "de", "DE" };

// case-insensitive distinct
var distinct = foo.Distinct(new KeyEqualityComparer<string>( x => x.ToLower() ) );
```

The `KeyEqualityComparer` class:

```
public class KeyEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, object> keyExtractor;

    public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T,object> keyExtractor)
    {
        this.keyExtractor = keyExtractor;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return this.keyExtractor(x).Equals(this.keyExtractor(y));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return this.keyExtractor(obj).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Comment: This is _much_ better than aku's answer.

Comment: Definitely the right approach. There are a couple improvements that can be made, in my opinion, which I've mentioned in my own answer.

Comment: This is very elegant code, but it doesn't answer the question, which is why I accepted @aku's answer instead. I wanted a wrapper for Func<T, T, bool> and I have no requirement to extract a key, since the key is already separated out in my Dictionary.

Comment: @Marcelo: That's fine, you can do that; but be aware that if you're going to take @aku's approach, you **really should** add a `Func<T, int>` to supply the hash code for a `T` value (as has been suggested in, e.g., [Ruben's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/3719617#3719617)). Otherwise the `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation you're left with is quite broken, *especially* with regards to its usefulness in LINQ extension methods. See my answer for a discussion on why this is.

Comment: This is nice but if the key being selected was a value type there would be unnecessary boxing. Perhaps would be better to have a TKey for defining the key.

Comment: @SLaks not only that this is better, the other is just wrong. Blame OP for accepting that as answer!

Comment: Why not generic `Tkey` instead of *boxed* `object`?

Comment: @nawfal you're right, of course, and Dan Tao's answer fixes that.

Comment: I cannot understand how to use this in the case of a dictionary eg

```
select new
{
  key = pair.First().UrlDecode(),
  value = pair.Length > 1 ? pair.Second().UrlDecode() : ""             
}).Distinct(//?).ToDictionary(k => k.key, v => v.value);
```

Answer (score 47):

I'm afraid there is no such wrapper out-of-box. However it's not hard to create one:

```
class Comparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _comparer;

    public Comparer(Func<T, T, bool> comparer)
    {
        if (comparer == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("comparer");

        _comparer = comparer;
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return _comparer(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return obj.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode();
    }
}

...

Func<int, int, bool> f = (x, y) => x == y;
var comparer = new Comparer<int>(f);
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(1, 1));
Console.WriteLine(comparer.Equals(1, 2));
```

Comment: Thats absolutely fantastic, cleans so much code up its ridiculous!

Comment: However, be careful with that implementation of GetHashCode. If you're actually going to be using it in some sort of hash table you'll want something a bit more robust.

Comment: this code has a serious problem! it is easy to come up with a class that has two objects that are equal in terms of this comparer but have different hash codes.

Comment: To remedy this, the class needs another member `private readonly Func<T, int> _hashCodeResolver` that must also be passed in the constructor and be used in the `GetHashCode(...)` method.

Comment: I'm curious: Why are you using `obj.ToString().ToLower().GetHashCode()` instead of `obj.GetHashCode()`?

Comment: The places in the framework that take an `IEqualityComparer<T>` invariably use hashing behind the scenes (e.g., LINQ's GroupBy, Distinct, Except, Join, etc) and the MS contract regarding hashing is broken in this implementation. Here's MS's documentation excerpt:
*"Implementations are required to ensure that if the Equals method returns true for two objects x and y, then the value returned by the GetHashCode method for x must equal the value returned for y."*
See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132155

Answer (score 26):

Same as Dan Tao's answer, but with a few improvements:

1. Relies on `EqualityComparer<>.Default` to do the actual comparing so that it avoids boxing for value types (`struct`s) that has implemented `IEquatable<>`.
2. Since `EqualityComparer<>.Default` used it doesn't explode on `null.Equals(something)`.
3. Provided static wrapper around `IEqualityComparer<>` which will have a static method to create the instance of comparer - eases calling. Compare

   ```
    Equality<Person>.CreateComparer(p => p.ID);
   ```

   with

   ```
    new EqualityComparer<Person, int>(p => p.ID);
   ```
4. Added an overload to specify `IEqualityComparer<>` for the key.

**The class:**

```
public static class Equality<T>
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer<V>(Func<T, V> keySelector)
    {
        return CreateComparer(keySelector, null);
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer<V>(Func<T, V> keySelector, 
                                                         IEqualityComparer<V> comparer)
    {
        return new KeyEqualityComparer<V>(keySelector, comparer);
    }

    class KeyEqualityComparer<V> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        readonly Func<T, V> keySelector;
        readonly IEqualityComparer<V> comparer;

        public KeyEqualityComparer(Func<T, V> keySelector, 
                                   IEqualityComparer<V> comparer)
        {
            if (keySelector == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));

            this.keySelector = keySelector;
            this.comparer = comparer ?? EqualityComparer<V>.Default;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y)
        {
            return comparer.Equals(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return comparer.GetHashCode(keySelector(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

you may use it like this:

```
var comparer1 = Equality<Person>.CreateComparer(p => p.ID);
var comparer2 = Equality<Person>.CreateComparer(p => p.Name);
var comparer3 = Equality<Person>.CreateComparer(p => p.Birthday.Year);
var comparer4 = Equality<Person>.CreateComparer(p => p.Name, StringComparer.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase);
```

Person is a simple class:

```
class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public DateTime Birthday { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: +1 for providing an implementation that lets you provide a comparer for the key. Besides giving more flexibility this also avoids boxing value types for both the comparisons and also the hashing.

Comment: This is the most fleshed out answer here. I added a null check as well. Complete.

Answer (score 11):

```
public class FuncEqualityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    readonly Func<T, T, bool> _comparer;
    readonly Func<T, int> _hash;

    public FuncEqualityComparer( Func<T, T, bool> comparer )
        : this( comparer, t => t.GetHashCode())
    {
    }

    public FuncEqualityComparer( Func<T, T, bool> comparer, Func<T, int> hash )
    {
        _comparer = comparer;
        _hash = hash;
    }

    public bool Equals( T x, T y )
    {
        return _comparer( x, y );
    }

    public int GetHashCode( T obj )
    {
        return _hash( obj );
    }
}
```

With extensions :-

```
public static class SequenceExtensions
{
    public static bool SequenceEqual<T>( this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, bool> comparer )
    {
        return first.SequenceEqual( second, new FuncEqualityComparer<T>( comparer ) );
    }

    public static bool SequenceEqual<T>( this IEnumerable<T> first, IEnumerable<T> second, Func<T, T, bool> comparer, Func<T, int> hash )
    {
        return first.SequenceEqual( second, new FuncEqualityComparer<T>( comparer, hash ) );
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sam (who no longer exists as of this comment): Cleaned up code without anjusting behavior (and +1'd). Added Riff at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/3719617#3719617

Answer (score 6):

orip's answer is great.

Here a little extension method to make it even easier:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Distinct<T>(this IEnumerable<T> list, Func<T, object>    keyExtractor)
{
    return list.Distinct(new KeyEqualityComparer<T>(keyExtractor));
}
var distinct = foo.Distinct(x => x.ToLower())
```

Answer (score 2):

I'm going to answer my own question. To treat Dictionaries as sets, the simplest method seems to be to apply set operations to dict.Keys, then convert back to Dictionaries with Enumerable.ToDictionary(...).

Answer (score 2):

The implementation at (german text) [Implementing IEqualityCompare with lambda expression](http://web.archive.org/web/20151126060513/http://flurfunk.sdx-ag.de/2013/06/linq-iequalitycomparer-durch-lambda.html)
cares about null values and uses extension methods to generate IEqualityComparer.

To create an IEqualityComparer in a Linq union your just have to write

```
persons1.Union(persons2, person => person.LastName)
```

The comparer:

```
public class LambdaEqualityComparer<TSource, TComparable> : IEqualityComparer<TSource>
{
  Func<TSource, TComparable> _keyGetter;
    
  public LambdaEqualityComparer(Func<TSource, TComparable> keyGetter)
  {
    _keyGetter = keyGetter;
  }
    
  public bool Equals(TSource x, TSource y)
  {
    if (x == null || y == null) return (x == null && y == null);
    return object.Equals(_keyGetter(x), _keyGetter(y));
  }
   
  public int GetHashCode(TSource obj)
  {
    if (obj == null) return int.MinValue;
    var k = _keyGetter(obj);
    if (k == null) return int.MaxValue;
    return k.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

You also need to add an extension method to support type inference

```
public static class LambdaEqualityComparer
{
       // source1.Union(source2, lambda)
        public static IEnumerable<TSource> Union<TSource, TComparable>(
           this IEnumerable<TSource> source1, 
           IEnumerable<TSource> source2, 
            Func<TSource, TComparable> keySelector)
        {
            return source1.Union(source2, 
               new LambdaEqualityComparer<TSource, TComparable>(keySelector));
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just one optimization:
We can use the out-of-the-box EqualityComparer for value comparisions, rather than delegating it.

This would also make the implementation cleaner as actual comparision logic now stays in GetHashCode() and Equals() which you may have already overloaded.

Here is the code:

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> 
{ 
  public bool Equals(T x, T y) 
  { 
    return EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(x, y); 
  } 

  public int GetHashCode(T obj) 
  { 
    return obj.GetHashCode(); 
  } 
}
```

Don't forget to overload GetHashCode() and Equals() methods on your object.

This post helped me: [c# compare two generic values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/488250/c-compare-two-generic-values)

Sushil

Comment: NB same issue as identified in comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/98119#98119 - CANT assume obj.GetHashCode() makes sense

Comment: I don't get the purpose of this one. You created an equality comparer that's equivalent to the default equality comparer. So why don't you use it directly?

Answer (score 1):

[orip's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1239337/1295274) is great. Expanding on orip's answer:

i think that the solution's key is use "Extension Method" to transfer the "anonymous type".

```
    public static class Comparer 
    {
      public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateComparerForElements<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, Func<T, object> keyExtractor)
      {
        return new KeyEqualityComparer<T>(keyExtractor);
      }
    }
```

Usage:

```
var n = ItemList.Select(s => new { s.Vchr, s.Id, s.Ctr, s.Vendor, s.Description, s.Invoice }).ToList();
n.AddRange(OtherList.Select(s => new { s.Vchr, s.Id, s.Ctr, s.Vendor, s.Description, s.Invoice }).ToList(););
n = n.Distinct(x=>new{Vchr=x.Vchr,Id=x.Id}).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static Dictionary<TKey, TValue> Distinct<TKey, TValue>(this IEnumerable<TValue> items, Func<TValue, TKey> selector)
  {
     Dictionary<TKey, TValue> result = null;
     ICollection collection = items as ICollection;
     if (collection != null)
        result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>(collection.Count);
     else
        result = new Dictionary<TKey, TValue>();
     foreach (TValue item in items)
        result[selector(item)] = item;
     return result;
  }
```

This makes it possible to select a property with lambda like this: `.Select(y => y.Article).Distinct(x => x.ArticleID);`

Answer (score 0):

```
public class DelegateEqualityComparer<T>: IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equalsDelegate;
    private readonly Func<T, int>     _getHashCodeDelegate;

    public DelegateEqualityComparer(Func<T, T, bool> equalsDelegate, Func<T, int> getHashCodeDelegate)
    {
        _equalsDelegate      = equalsDelegate      ?? ((tx, ty) => object.Equals(tx, ty));
        _getHashCodeDelegate = getHashCodeDelegate ?? (t => t.GetSafeHashCode());
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y) => _equalsDelegate(x, y);

    public int GetHashCode(T obj) => _getHashCodeDelegate(obj);
}
```

Comment: Please don't post code-only answers. The main audience, future readers, will be grateful to see explained *why* this answers the question instead of having to infer it from the code. Also, since this is an old question, please explain how it complements the other answers.

Answer (score 0):

Adding nullable reference types annotation's to [ldp615's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6913646/682203).

```cs
public static class Equality<T> where T : class
{
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer<V>(Func<T, V> keySelector) where V : notnull
    {
        return CreateComparer(keySelector, EqualityComparer<V>.Default);
    }

    public static IEqualityComparer<T> CreateComparer<V>(
        Func<T, V> keySelector,
        IEqualityComparer<V> comparer)
        where V : notnull
    {
        return new KeyEqualityComparer<V>(keySelector, comparer);
    }

    class KeyEqualityComparer<V> : IEqualityComparer<T> where V : notnull
    {
        readonly Func<T, V> keySelector;
        readonly IEqualityComparer<V> comparer;

        public KeyEqualityComparer(
            Func<T, V> keySelector,
            IEqualityComparer<V> comparer)
        {
            if (keySelector == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(keySelector));
            if (comparer == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(comparer));

            this.keySelector = keySelector;
            this.comparer = comparer;
        }

        public bool Equals(T? x, T? y)
        {
            if (x == null || y == null)
            {
                if(x == y)
                {
                    return true;
                }

                return false;
            }

            return comparer.Equals(keySelector(x), keySelector(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(T obj)
        {
            return comparer.GetHashCode(keySelector(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I don't know of an existing class but something like:

```
public class MyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
{
  private Func<T, T, bool> _compare;
  MyComparer(Func<T, T, bool> compare)
  {
    _compare = compare;
  }

  public bool Equals(T x, Ty)
  {
    return _compare(x, y);
  }

  public int GetHashCode(T obj)
  {
    return obj.GetHashCode();
  }
}
```

Note: I haven't actually compiled and run this yet, so there might be a typo or other bug.

Comment: NB same issue as identified in comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/98119#98119 - CANT assume obj.GetHashCode() makes sense