# How to avoid duplicates in LINQ for an anonymous type?

Tags: c#, linq

I am trying to convert a `DataTable` to a Dictionary of string and integer. DataTable has duplicates and I had written the following code:

```
Dictionary<string, short> data = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                   .Select(item => new {
                                                          Key = item.Field<string>("product_name"),
                                                          Value = item.Field<short>("type_id")
                                                        })
                                    .Distinct()
                                    .ToDictionary(dr => dr.Key, dr => dr.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

When I have data like this:

```
Product1   1
Product1   2
Product2   3
Product4   3
```

the result should be this:

```
Product1   1
Product2   3
Product4   3
```

My code is erroring out as the Distinct() considers all the available properties in the anonymous type. Is there a way to achieve this linq or overwrite the default behavior of Distinct()?

Comment: How many properties are involved in determining if it's distinct?  Is it just the key?

Comment: Yes, Just the key. I need get all the distinct product_name with the corresponding type_id (this can be first the first occurrence of the key).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this (distinct by Key):

```
Dictionary<string, short> data = dt.AsEnumerable()
                                       .Select(item => new {
                                                              Key = item.Field<string>("product_name"),
                                                              Value = item.Field<short>("type_id")
                                                            })
                                        .GroupBy(x=>x.Key)
                                        .Select(x=>x.First())
                                        .ToDictionary(dr => dr.Key, dr => dr.Value, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Yep.  That's what I was going to suggest, too.

Answer (score 1):

You can provide an implementation of IEqualityComparer to `Distinct()` as per the docs: https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bb338049(v=vs.100).aspx

You can create such an equality comparer for your anonymous type as described in this stack overflow answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1071637/1675729