# How to group by age and gender with IComparable?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq-to-sql

like the title said I have to group by age and gender but I get this error message:

> At least one object must implement IComparable

```
var ageStats = vModel
               .GroupBy(l => new { Age = 10 * (l.Age / 10), l.GenderName })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Key)
               .Select(g => new
                            {
                                Name = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Select(l => l.Age).Count()
                            })
               .ToList();
```

If I group by age only like that it will work `.GroupBy(l => 10 * (l.Age / 10))` but I won't have the gender.

Comment: What's the type of `GenderName`?

Comment: The type of GenderName is string

Comment: have you tried using tuples instead of anonymous objects?

Comment: @Luiso's suggestion of using Tuples is a good one.  Tuples implement `IComparable`.

Comment: @Luiso Tuples are almost always a bad idea, just create a class, especially as it looks like OP is going to use the result as is.

Comment: @Luiso IMHO, Tuples are a bad idea when you return them from an API or, in general, a method from a class. All you can see is the type of each element, but you have no idea what each element represents. If you use the Tuple wholly within the LINQ query, then it wouldn't be as bad because you can simply glance up to see what each element represents.

Comment: You might could do something like http://stackoverflow.com/a/1071637/884561, where you pass an instance of your new `IEqualityComparer` to the `GroupBy` as a second parameter.

Comment: @KennethK. I agree with you, but if that query is being used inside a method, and you know what you're doing, they can save some time and having to implement an almost useless class

Comment: @Luiso Sorry, I meant to direct that comment toward DavidG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you ordering your group results you using `Key` that in your case is complex anonymouse type contains 2 fields:

```
var ageStats = vModel
               .GroupBy(l => new { Age = 10 * (l.Age / 10), l.GenderName })
               .OrderBy(x => x.Key) //<-- this line
               .Select(g => new
                            {
                                Name = g.Key,
                                Count = g.Select(l => l.Age).Count()
                            })
               .ToList();
```

It works with only `Age` grouping becouse anonymouse type in this case simple `int` field.

If you want to order your results somehow you should point to field like this:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Age)
```

Or this:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Key.GenderName)
```

If you want to order first by `Age` then by `GenderName` use `ThenBy` extension method like this:

```
.OrderBy(x => x.Key.Age).ThenBy(x => x.Key.GenderName)
```

Answer (score -1):

When you do:

```
new { Age = 10 * (l.Age / 10), l.GenderName }
```

you're creating an anonymous type, which I don't believe implements `IComparable`.  When you leave out the braces and the `, l.GenderName`, the result of the expression is an `int`, which does implement `IComparable`.

Comment: Leaving out the `, l.GenderName` wouldn't perform the group that he wants.

Comment: I think this answer explains the compilation error, but @Luiso's comment about Tuples on the original post provides a good answer.

Comment: @KennethK., I wasn't suggesting that this would perform the grouping he wanted.  But point taken:  this wasn't an 'answer', so I should've posted it as a comment.

Comment: @wablab your answer correct, it's more like x y problem.