# Is there any kind of "ReferenceComparer" in .NET?

Tags: c#, .net, comparison, base-class-library

There are several places in BCL where one can make use of [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx). Like [Enumerable.Contains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb339118.aspx) or [Dictionary Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132072.aspx). I can provide my comparer if I'm not happy with the [default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms224763.aspx) one.

Sometimes I want to know whether the collection contains *that very object* that I have reference to. Not the one that is considered "equal" in any other meaning.
The question is: **whether there exists standard equality comparer in the BCL that relies only on [ReferenceEquals](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.referenceequals.aspx) method?**

The one that I wrote myself is this:

```
class ReferenceComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T> where T : class
{
    private static ReferenceComparer<T> m_instance;

    public static ReferenceComparer<T> Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return m_instance ?? (m_instance = new ReferenceComparer<T>());
        }
    }

    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

I didn't test it thoroughly nor considered lots of scenarios, but it seems to make `Enumerable.Contains` and `Dictionary` pretty happy.

Comment: It's unfortunate that all these collections are written in a Java-esque way, requiring you to write a class that implements a specific interface.  If only they allowed you to pass in a delegate to specify the comparison operator, you could pass `object.ReferenceEquals` directly.  I guess it's because two methods are needed (comparison and hashcode).

Comment: As I understand it, though, the Java counterpart to `IEqualityComparer` doesn't have a `GetHashCode`, so it *could* be implemented as a delegate in Java if Java supported delegates.

Comment: @Ben look at orip's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/1239337#1239337

Comment: @Hellfrost: great link.  Too bad none of those were included with .NET.

Comment: One could define a `DelegateQualityComparer<T>` that takes two delegates(one for equality, one for hashcode). And one that takes only one delegate mapping the compared type to the result of a delegate and comparing that one could be useful too as comparing a property is a common scenario.

Comment: too bad .net has references at all...

Comment: @CodeInChaos: That's (a `DelegateEqualityComparer` implementation) pretty much the point of the link Hellfrost gave.

Comment: I mean that Reference Types are semantically strange and wrong, and conflict with value types, and its too bad that C# inherited this defect from Java. Reference types were supposed to be a remedy to the issues brought to C++ by pointers, but its completely like spilling the bath watter with the baby.

Comment: See also: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890058/iequalitycomparert-that-uses-referenceequals

Comment: See my update of the implementation to .Net4.0 [as an answer to a similar question here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35520207/533837) - in short the comparer doesn't need to be generic anymore thanks to contravariance on the interface! (Which simplifies usage and saves a tiny bit of memory.)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As far as I know, the BCL doesn't expose any public types that implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` with reference-equality as of .NET 4.0 .

However, there do appear to be  a bunch of internal types that do this,  such as:

- `System.Dynamic.Utils.ReferenceEqualityComparer<T>`
  (in System.Core)
- `System.Xaml.Schema.ReferenceEqualityComparer<T>`
  (in System.Xaml).

I took a look at the implementations of these two types with reflector, and you'll be happy to know that both of them appear to be implemented in a way that is virtually *identical* to yours, except that they don't use lazy-initialization for the static instance (they create it in the static constructor for the type).

The only possible 'issue' I can think of with your implementation is that the lazy-initialization is not thread-safe, but since instances are 'cheap' and aren't holding onto any state, that shouldn't create any bugs or major performance problems. If you want to *enforce* the singleton-pattern though, you'll have to do it properly.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning my lazy-initialization failure. For this class it looks meaningful to initialize the instance in the static constructor. However, thanks to you, I'll not make the same mistake anywhere else.

Comment: @alpha-mouse: Cheers. I would say that I wouldn't feel obligated to make a class thread-safe just for the sake of it, unless I intend to *use* it in a manner that requires it.

Comment: There is also `System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.ObjectReferenceEqualityComparer`.

Comment: `namespace System.Dynamic.Utils { internal sealed class ReferenceEqualityComparer { ...} }`: `internal` prohibits any direct use by us, and `sealed` also prohibits any indirect use. :-(

Answer (score 3):

I end up using this solution also as I could not find any workaround.

To fix the non thread safe implementation, you could easily use a static initiailizer.

```
public static ReferenceComparer<T> Instance => new ReferenceComparer<T>();
```

(sorry for the answer instead of a comment to up-voted thread, I have a new account with no comment rights, yet).