# Parse JSON ISO8601 date in C++/CX

Tags: c++, microsoft-metro, windows-runtime, atl, c++-cx

I have a date string coming from JSON "2012-08-01T15:42:06Z" and want to parse that in Windows Runtime. As far as I know, only **COleDateTime** is available to handle this.

I can only get it to correctly parse the string when I take out the 'T' & 'Z' characters, but that adds an extra parsing step on my end.

**WORKS:**

```
COleDateTime dateTime;
dateTime.ParseDateTime(L"2012-08-01 15:42:06", 0UL, 1033UL);
```

**FAILS:**

```
COleDateTime dateTime;
dateTime.ParseDateTime(L"2012-08-01T15:42:06Z", 0UL, 1033UL);
```

Anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If your date string is formatted consistently, you can use `std::get_time` to parse the time into a `tm` struct, copy the relevant bits into a `SYSTEMTIME` and from there convert to a `FILETIME` and then to `Windows::Foundation::DateTime`.

Info on `std::get_time`: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/get_time

Code for converting from `SYSTEMTIME` to `DateTime`: [How do I parse a date in a Metro (C++/CX) app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11615998/how-do-i-parse-a-date-in-a-metro-c-cx-app)