# Why derive from Comparer<T> class rather than implement class that implements IComparer<T> interface?

Tags: c#

[MS documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) notes that it is better to derive from Comparer class rather than implement class that implements `IComparer<T>` interface.

> We recommend that you derive from the Comparer class instead of
>   implementing the IComparer interface, because the Comparer class
>   provides an explicit interface implementation of the IComparer.Compare
>   method and the Default property that gets the default comparer for the
>   object.

So why derive from Comparer in order to create custom comparator ?

Comment: The answer is in the quote... If you don't need the non-generic `IComparer` implementation, then don't follow the advice. Don't forget, recommendations, guidelines, and advice are all optional.

Comment: -1 because your claim that it gives no reason is simply not true.

Comment: The point about the `Default` property is simply incorrect; that will not ever return custom subclass

Comment: @MarcGravell I think it's correct, but not what you think it means. A custom derived class might use `Default` as part of its implementation.

Comment: @hvd yes, but since `Default` is public, a custom non-derived class might **equally** use `Default` as part of its implementation

Comment: @MarcGravell Sure, but it would then need to be prefixed by `Comparer<T>.`. I'm reading the quote as saying `Default` is easier to access.

Comment: but @marc documentation doesn't claims `Default` property will return custom subclass ever. but it is confusing enough.

Comment: @hvd the chances of a custom comparer needing to access the default comparer **of the same type** are virtually nil. I can see how it might want to access the default comparer of *encapsulated types* (i.e. types that the `T` in question has as properties), but to do that would require the `Comparer<SomeType>` prefix. I geuninely don't see that this MS guidance adds anything of any use.

Comment: @MarcGravell I can think of one (but only one) example: a `ReverseComparer` class that returns positive when the default comparer returns negative, and vice versa.

Comment: @hvd I'll grant you that one, but frankly - it isn't exactly a huge saving!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main benefit is that this makes your comparer implement the non-generic IComparer interface for free, which can be useful when interoping with legacy APIs or if you want to be able to store a collection of comparers for different types.

Check out [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5707347/preferring-equalitycomparert-to-iequalitycomparert)

Comment: that's an entire line of saved code! (not a dig at you, note)