# IEqualityComparer<T> does not work with List<T>.Distinct() method

Tags: c#, .net, linq, iequalitycomparer

I have the following simple object:

```
public class Net : IEqualityComparer<Net>
{
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    public int Id { get; set; }

    private Gate _inGate;
    private Gate _outGate;
    private NetValue _value = NetValue.NotSet;
    private bool _isMiddleNet;

    //constructor and stuff!!!.....

    //Equality comparer
    public bool Equals(Net x, Net y)
    {
        return (x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Net obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        return 13 * Id.GetHashCode() + 7 * Name.GetHashCode();
    }
```

So basically I am interested to say 2 instance of this object are equal if and only if their `Id` and `Name` members are equal...

But somewhere else in another class I have to `List<Net>` and I want to perform distinction on these lists:

```
    inputNetsA = inputNetsA.Distinct().ToList();
    inputNetsB = inputNetsB.Distinct().ToList();
```

But this does not work what so ever! What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Side q: why 2 implementations of GetHashCode are so different in your sample? And where is `object.Equals` implementation? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095395/whats-the-role-of-gethashcode-in-the-iequalitycomparert-in-net and linked questions for info...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make the objects [`IEquatable<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187.aspx). The [`IEqualityComparer<T>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) is an interface for objects that compares two objects with eachother.  The `IEquatable<T>` is used for comparing an object with another object of the same type.

Otherwise, if you wanted to use `IEqualityComparer<T>`, it's meant to be passed in to the `Distinct()` method.

```
// better to extend off of EqualityComparer<T> instead of
//     implementing IEqualityComparer<T> directly
public class NetComparer : EqualityComparer<Net>
{
    public override bool Equals(Net x, Net y)
    {
        return (x.Id == y.Id && x.Name == y.Name);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode(Net obj)
    {
        return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Name.GetHashCode();
    }
}

inputNetsA = inputNetsA.Distinct(new NetComparer()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I get NullReference on this line `return obj.Id.GetHashCode() ^ obj.Name.GetHashCode();`

Comment: Is it ok if I just return null in GetHashCode?

Comment: The return type of `GetHashCode()` is `int`, you can't return `null`. All I can really say about that is, return whatever is appropriate for that type. If one of the members of the object that is used to generate a hash code can be `null`, then maybe it's not a suitable key? Otherwise, you need to decide on a way to deal with them.  e.g., treat them as `0`

Comment: What is the advantage of *better to extend off of `EqualityComparer<T>` instead of implementing `IEqualityComparer<T>` directly*? I haven't ever heard of it, and in the end the interface has two methods, and the `EqualityComparer<T>` has two abstract methods (that are the same)...

Comment: @JeffMercado Ignore it... Seen your other response... http://stackoverflow.com/a/5707968/613130 . The class implements the non-generic versions by calling the generic (overloadable) version.