# Authorize a each user to do things to themselves only

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, claims-based-identity

I have a working authorization based on roles like this.

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Super, Common")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class MemberController : Controller
{
  ...
  [HttpGet("Member/{id}")]
  public IActionResult GetMember(Guid id)
  {
    Member output;
    ...
    return Ok(output);
  }
}
```

The problem now is that **any** member can see **any other**. I'd like the method to be authorized so that:

If the given member has the  role of "common" (the ID is in the claims), they can fetch info about themselves.

If the given member has the role of "super", they can fetch info about themselves but also about any other member in their organization.

If the given member has the role of "admin", they can fetch info about themselves and any member in their organization but also about any other member in the database as a whole.

My way to resolve it is to build in logic in the controller fetching and checking. However, I know that there are security policies in the framework, which can be configured in the *Start* class.

I wonder if said task is possible to resolve using policy configuration to begin with or if I'm doomed to hack the logic myself in the method of the controller. I can't determine it myself as I lack the competence. Is that a feasible strategy?

Comment: Isnt this just a guard where you check if user is in role, then fetch all, else fetch only member?

Comment: @McBoman Not really, no. *Admin* role is easy, yes - if the user is *admin* they may look up any member. But if they are in *super* role, they may only look up the members in the organization they belong to themselves (there will be multiple organizations available). And if the user is *common* roled, they can only look up themselves and nobody else.

Comment: Don't use roles, use claims instead and check if a claim exists. Roles are too inflexible and they are not recommended to be used. Though you can still assign claims to roles which will be added to the users claims when he logs in. With claims you could also have an claims array such as `organizations: ["orgId1", "orgId2"]` to allow a user access multiple organizations resources which you can't as good with roles

Comment: Also have a look at [Resource-based authorization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/resourcebased?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x). Also check my [previous 
 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45404984/455493)