# How to create json string from C# list of object with specific properties?

Tags: c#, json, list, c#-3.0

Consider I have below values in the drop-down (`dropDownList` variable) and user selected values are in `selectedDropDownValues` list.

And DB api returns the list of customers (`customerDBList` variable).

Now the requirement is to build JSON from selected values as mentioned below -

```
var dropDownList = new[] { "Customer.Id", "Customer.FirstName", "Customer.LastName", "Customer.Address.AddressLine1", "Customer.Address.AddressLine2" };

var selectedDropDownValues = new[] { "Customer.Id", "Customer.FirstName", "Customer.Address.AddressLine1" };

var customerDBList = new List<Customer>(){
                new Customer {
                    Id=1,
                    FirstName="John",
                    LastName="Desouza",
                    Address=new Address{            
                                AddressLine1="1 Street",
                                AddressLine2="Linking Road"
                    }},        
                new Customer {
                    Id=2,
                    FirstName="Sam",
                    LastName="Lewis",
                    Address=new Address{            
                                AddressLine1="Fedral Highway",
                                AddressLine2="Louisville"
                    }                
                }};
```

Expected JSON output as -

```
[
  {
    "Customer": {
      "Id": 1,
      "FirstName": "John",
      "Address": {
        "AddressLine1": "1 Street"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Customer": {
      "Id": 2,
      "FirstName": "Sam",
      "Address": {
        "AddressLine1": "Fedral Highway"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Could you clarify if you want both address lines together or not?  Your example shows it both ways.

Comment: No I want as per the selected values in selectedDropDownValues

Comment: I have updated the JSON.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it happens, your `selectedDropDownValues` strings `"Customer.Address.AddressLine1"` are in [JSONPath](http://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/) syntax, so you could convert your `Customer` objects to an intermediate [`JObject`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject.htm) then prune unwanted values using `JsonExtensions.RemoveAllExcept(this JObject obj, IEnumerable<string> paths)` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30333562/3744182) to *[How to perform partial object serialization providing "paths" using Newtonsoft JSON.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30304128/3744182)*.

Note that your desired JSON has an extra level of nesting `{ "Customer": { ... } }` not present in your data model, so it will need to be manually inserted before filtering:

```
var rootName = "Customer";

var query = customerDBList
    // Convert to JObject
    .Select(c => JObject.FromObject(c))
    // Add additional level of object nesting { "Customer": { ... } } 
    .Select(o => new JObject( new JProperty(rootName, o)))
    // Remove all but selected properties.
    .Select(o => o.RemoveAllExcept(selectedDropDownValues));

var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(query, Formatting.Indented);
```

Working sample .Net fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/m6FdSg) which shows the generated JSON to be, as required,

```
[
  {
    "Customer": {
      "Id": 1,
      "FirstName": "John",
      "Address": {
        "AddressLine1": "1 Street"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "Customer": {
      "Id": 2,
      "FirstName": "Sam",
      "Address": {
        "AddressLine1": "Fedral Highway"
      }
    }
  }
]
```