# C# ReferenceSet<T>

Tags: c#, .net

I need a "Reference Set," that is, a set that is pretty much a Hash Set but uses it's object's references rather than their hash codes. Where can I find such a class, or how can I implement one? For clarification, I don't care if it works internally like a hash set using references, I just want it to behave like it from the outside. I'd rather not use external libraries, but links to the source code of libraries that have such a set would be welcome (so I can use that to figure out how to implement one myself).

Comment: This feels like a XY Problem - https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem . **Why** do you want this?

Comment: Can you talk us through why you can't use `HashSet` using `ReferenceEqualityComparer`? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1890058/iequalitycomparert-that-uses-referenceequals

Comment: @mjwills I didn't know HashSets could accept IEqualityComparers. Thanks for the quick solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard `HashSet<T>` allows you to provide a custom comparer, and that comparer is responsible for hashing and performing equality checks on set elements.  Give it an identity comparer, and you'll get the functionality you describe.

```
public sealed class IdentityComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    where T : class
{
    public bool Equals(T x, T y)
    {
        return ReferenceEquals(x, y);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
        return System.Runtime.CompilerServices.RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

Comment: "The RuntimeHelpers.GetHashCode method always calls the Object.GetHashCode", so how is different from the standard HashSet ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman That's exactly how it's different. Given e.g. a string, it will call the `Object.GetHashCode` method, meaning non-virtually, *not* the `String.GetHashCode` implementation that a virtual call to `GetHashCode` would result in.

Comment: This is exactly what I need, thanks!

Comment: @hvd - ok, fair point. Still an XY question though. Under what circumstance will this be better? For `HashSet<string>` for example?