# type-agnostic implementation of a generic interface

Tags: linq, generics, types, covariance, contravariance

I have some classes that override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`, but every now and then I need to compare by reference. So I have written a `ReferenceEqualityComparer` like here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35520207/5333340

Note that `ReferenceEqualityComparer` implements `IEqualityComparer<object>`.
Due to its contravariance I am not limited to collections of `object`s, i.e. I can write

```
ISet<MyClass> setOfMyClass = new HashSet<MyClass>(ReferenceEqualityComparer.Default);
```

. But it seems that in some situations, the contravariance will not help: I'd like to use my `ReferenceEqualityComparer` inside the method

```
Enumerable.ToDictionary<TSource, TKey, TElement>(this IEnumerable<TSource> source, Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector, Func<TSource, TElement> elementSelector, IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer)
```

like so (just a small technical example, I know there is no point using `ReferenceEqualityComparer` here):

```
var foo = new List<string> {"hello", "world", "to", "everyone"}
Dictionary<string, int> dict = foo.ToDictionary(x => x, x => x.Length, ReferenceEqualityComparer.Default);
```

Unfortunately, this does not work. Since the `ReferenceEqualityComparer` implements `IEqualityComparer<object>`, the resulting dictionary will be of type `Dictionary<object, int>` (that's what Visual Studio tells me). So if I understand correctly, in order to get `Dictionary<string, int>`, `ReferenceEqualityComparer` would need to implement `IEqualityComparer<string>`.

**So how do I make `ReferenceEqualityComparer` type-agnostic, i.e. make it implement `IEqualityComparer<T>` for all possible types `T`?**

Or am I mixing something up and there is another way? I'm not so much interested in theoretical concepts, I just want some way of using a non-generic class (here: `ReferenceEqualityComparer`) in a context where a generic class is expected.

Comment: For reasons I haven't looked into, `ToDictionary` sets `TKey` to the `IEqualityComparer` type and not the `Func<TSource,TKey> keySelector` type...?

Comment: I think your problem will be that `ReferenceEqualityComparer<T>.Default` can't have `T` inferred when passed as a parameter.