# Use of Distinct with list of custom objects

Tags: c#, linq, list, distinct-values

How can I make the `Distinct()` method work with a list of custom object (`Href` in this case), here is what the current object looks like:

```
public class Href : IComparable, IComparer<Href>
{
    public Uri URL { get; set; }
    public UrlType URLType { get; set; }

    public Href(Uri url, UrlType urltype)
    {
        URL = url;
        URLType = urltype;
    }


    #region IComparable Members

    public int CompareTo(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Href)
        {
            return URL.ToString().CompareTo((obj as Href).URL.ToString());
        }
        else
            throw new ArgumentException("Wrong data type.");
    }

    #endregion

    #region IComparer<Href> Members

    int IComparer<Href>.Compare(Href x, Href y)
    {
        return string.Compare(x.URL.ToString(), y.URL.ToString());
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You need to override `Equals` and `GetHashCode`.

`GetHashCode` should return the same value for all instances that are considered equal.

For example:

```
public override bool Equals(object obj) { 
    Href other = obj as Href;
    return other != null && URL.Equals(other.URL);
} 

public override int GetHashCode() { 
    return URL.GetHashCode();
}
```

Since .Net's Uri class overrides GetHashCode, you can simply return the URL's hashcode.

Comment: i am not quite sure why we are overriding a method of the interface

Comment: @Burnzy: There is no interface involved here.  These methods are inherited from `Object`.

Answer (score 0):

You could grab a copy of [aku's comparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer) (beware of the `GetHashCode` implementation however), and then write something like this

```
hrefList.Distinct(new Comparer<Href>((h1,h2)=>h1.URL==h2.URL))
```

Comment: Yes it does, and that's pretty cool stuff, however, I'm not quite sure how the aku's comparer delegate/readonly is mapping to a method

Comment: However, it will work very slowly since all of the hashcodes are the same.

Comment: Why when i Dont use h1.URL its not working (even though I override ToString())?

Comment: Because you didn't make an `==` operator.

Comment: Heh, yeah it works now, weirdly I thought == was mapping to CompareTo by default, but this make sens :)

ty ill give you credit.

Comment: No.  `==` compares by reference.  This `IEqualityComparer` is **wrong** and should not be used.  Instead, use [orip's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/1239337#1239337), which implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` correctly.  (Or just override `GetHashCode` in the `Href` class itself)