# Anonymous IComparer implementation

Tags: c#

Is it possible to define an anonymous implementation of IComparer?

I believe Java allows anonymous classes to be defined inline - does C#?

Looking at this code I want to define a custom `IComparer` inline

```
public static IOrderedEnumerable<TSource> OrderBy<TSource, TKey>(
    this IEnumerable<TSource> source,
    Func<TSource, TKey> keySelector,
    IComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

Comment: This is my workaround: https://github.com/smartcaveman/anonymous

Comment: You have an answer in a related question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1071637/661933

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, C# does not currently allow inline interface implementations; although it *does* allow you to create *delegates* inline through lambda expressions and anonymous methods.

In your case, I would suggest using a `ProjectionComparer` that makes it easy to use this feature, such as the one listed  [here](https://github.com/jskeet/edulinq/blob/55f26252cc6daf837e5293ab7a84c54d6c34697d/src/Edulinq/ProjectionComparer.cs).

Comment: @ChloeRadshaw: Java does allow anonymous inner classes that implement interfaces, but it currently has no first-class function concept (such as delegates).

Answer (score 59):

As indicated in one of the comments below, .Net 4.5 allows this via a static method on the Comparer<> class, e.g. comparing two objects based on the value of a property in the class:

```
var comparer = Comparer<KilowattSnapshot>.Create( 
        (k1, k2) => k1.Kilowatt.CompareTo(k2.Kilowatt) );
```

Obviously this can be used inline rather than assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 16):

Even though you can't create anonymous classes that implement interfaces, you can usually use the [Comparison Delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tfakywbh.aspx) instead of the [IComparer Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8ehhxeaf.aspx) in most cases (like sorting, etc.):

```
Array.Sort(arr, (x, y) => 1);
```

Also there are some built-in implementations of `IComparer` like the [Comparer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cfttsh47.aspx) or the [StringComparer Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.stringcomparer.aspx)...

Comment: With the upcoming .NET4.5 (Visual Studio 2012) it will be possible to make an `IComparer<>` from a `Comparison<>` lambda arrow by using the new factory method `Comparer<>.Create`.

Comment: Only thing is `Comparer<>.Create` is extremely ugly to use, because it can't infer arguments (contrast this with how `Tuple.Create` and `Tuple<>` interact).

Answer (score 14):

The .NET framework version 4.5 provides the method [Comparer.Create(Comparison)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/hh737198.aspx) to create comparers based on a specified comparison delegate (which can be a lambda function). However people who are working with earlier versions of .NET will probably need to implement something similar themselves.

Answer (score 3):

No, this is not possible. However, you can get the default implementation of `IComparer<TKey>` by `Comparer<TKey>.Default`. Otherwise you'll need to create a parameterized implementation and use an instance of that.

Answer (score 2):

C# does not allow implementing interfaces using anonymous inner classes inline, unlike Java. For simple comparisons (i.e. comparing on a single key), there is a better way to do this in C#. You can simply use the `.OrderBy()` method and pass in a lambda expression specifying the key.

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;


namespace Test{
    public class Test{
        public static void Main(){
            IList<int> mylist = new List<int>();
            for(int i=0; i<10; i++) mylist.Add(i);
            var sorted = mylist.OrderBy( x => -x );
            foreach(int x in sorted)
                Console.WriteLine(x);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at these 2 SO questions, they tackle essentially the same problem

[Use of Distinct with list of Custom Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3006733/use-of-distinct-with-list-of-custom-object)

[Wrap a delegate in an IEqualityComparer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer)

If you go this way, you should pay special attention to Slaks' comments and [Dan Tao's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer) about the hashcode implementation

Answer (score 1):

```
Array.Sort(arrayName, (x,y) => string.Compare(x.Name,y.Name,StringComparison.CurrentCulture));
```