# Pass a lambda expression in place of IComparer or IEqualityComparer or any single-method interface?

Tags: linq, extension-methods, ienumerable, iequalitycomparer, icomparer

I happened to have seen some code where this guy passed a lambda expression to a ArrayList.Sort(IComparer here) or a IEnumerable.SequenceEqual(IEnumerable list, IEqualityComparer here) where an IComparer or an IEqualityComparer was expected.

I can't be sure if I saw it though, or I am just dreaming. And I can't seem to find an extension on any of these collections that accepts a Func<> or a delegate in their method signatures.

Is there such an overload/extension method? Or, if not, is it possible to muck around like this and pass an algorithm (read delegate) where a single-method interface is expected?

**Update**
Thanks, everyone. That's what I thought. I must've been dreaming. I know how to write a conversion. I just wasn't sure if I'd seen something like that or just thought I'd seen it.

**Yet another update**
Look, here, I found one such instance. I wasn't dreaming after all. Look at [what this guy is doing here](http://www.revindex.com/?TabId=65&EntryID=23). What gives?

**And here's another update:**
Ok, I get it. The guy's using the `Comparison<T>` overload. Nice. Nice, but totally prone to mislead you. Nice, though. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wrap a delegate in an IEqualityComparer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer)

Comment: @nawfal: That is a different question. They are somewhat related but still different. That's a very nice question, though. Thanks for sharing. I found it very interesting. :-)

Comment: Oh yes I see now, but very close :P I retracted the close vote, but I will keep the comment so that other visitors do notice. One thing, kindly do accept answers. I think the top voted answer answers your question.

Answer (score 38):

I'm not much sure what useful it really is, as I think for most cases in the Base Library expecting an IComparer there's an overload that expects a Comparison... but just for the record:

in .Net 4.5 they've added a method to obtain an IComparer from a Comparison:
[Comparer.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198%28VS.110%29.aspx)

so you can pass your lambda to it and obtain an IComparer.

Comment: It would be relatively simple to add an Extension Method to .NET 4 which accomplishes the same thing.

Comment: Is there something similar available for EqualityComparer? It doesn't have a Create method but it seems very strange to add this useful method for Comparer and not EqualityComparer

Comment: @rdans `EqualityComparer` uses different signature, and, also, uses `GetHashCode` method. So you can't easily create comparer for this.

Answer (score 35):

I was also googling the web for a solution, but i didn't found any satisfying one. So i've created a generic EqualityComparerFactory:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

/// <summary>
/// Utility class for creating <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}"/> instances 
/// from Lambda expressions.
/// </summary>
public static class EqualityComparerFactory
{
    /// <summary>Creates the specified <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}" />.</summary>
    /// <typeparam name="T">The type to compare.</typeparam>
    /// <param name="getHashCode">The get hash code delegate.</param>
    /// <param name="equals">The equals delegate.</param>
    /// <returns>An instance of <see cref="IEqualityComparer{T}" />.</returns>
    public static IEqualityComparer<T> Create<T>(
        Func<T, int> getHashCode,
        Func<T, T, bool> equals)
    {
        if (getHashCode == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(getHashCode));
        }

        if (equals == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(equals));
        }

        return new Comparer<T>(getHashCode, equals);
    }

    private class Comparer<T> : IEqualityComparer<T>
    {
        private readonly Func<T, int> _getHashCode;
        private readonly Func<T, T, bool> _equals;

        public Comparer(Func<T, int> getHashCode, Func<T, T, bool> equals)
        {
            _getHashCode = getHashCode;
            _equals = equals;
        }

        public bool Equals(T x, T y) => _equals(x, y);

        public int GetHashCode(T obj) => _getHashCode(obj);
    }
}
```

The idea is, that the CreateComparer method takes two arguments: a delegate to GetHashCode(T) and a delegate to Equals(T,T)

Example:

```
class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var list1 = new List<Person>(new[]{
            new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Walter", LastName = "White" },
            new Person { Id = 2, FirstName = "Jesse", LastName = "Pinkman" },
            new Person { Id = 3, FirstName = "Skyler", LastName = "White" },
            new Person { Id = 4, FirstName = "Hank", LastName = "Schrader" },
        });

        var list2 = new List<Person>(new[]{
            new Person { Id = 1, FirstName = "Walter", LastName = "White" },
            new Person { Id = 4, FirstName = "Hank", LastName = "Schrader" },
        });


        // We're comparing based on the Id property
        var comparer = EqualityComparerFactory.Create<Person>(
            a => a.Id.GetHashCode(),
            (a, b) => a.Id==b.Id);
        var intersection = list1.Intersect(list2, comparer).ToList();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

You can provide a lambda for a Array.Sort method, as it requires a method that accepts two objects of type T and returns an integer. As such, you could provide a lambda of the following definition `(a, b) => a.CompareTo(b)`. An example to do a descending sort of an integer array:

```
int[] array = { 1, 8, 19, 4 };

// descending sort 
Array.Sort(array, (a, b) => -1 * a.CompareTo(b));
```

Comment: Can you explain this further? Is this a behavior unique to the IComparer<T> interface, or will it work on any interface that only has a single method on it?

Comment: @Stripling, I believe this is actually using the overload that accepts a `Comparison<T>`, as `Comparison` is a delegate that accepts the two parameters and returns the integer. As such, providing a valid lambda qualifies for this overload.

Answer (score 7):

```
public class Comparer2<T, TKey> : IComparer<T>, IEqualityComparer<T>
{
    private readonly Expression<Func<T, TKey>> _KeyExpr;
    private readonly Func<T, TKey> _CompiledFunc
    // Constructor
    public Comparer2(Expression<Func<T, TKey>> getKey)
    {
        _KeyExpr = getKey;
        _CompiledFunc = _KeyExpr.Compile();
    } 

    public int Compare(T obj1, T obj2)
    {
        return Comparer<TKey>.Default.Compare(_CompiledFunc(obj1), _CompiledFunc(obj2));
    }

    public bool Equals(T obj1, T obj2)
    { 
        return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.Equals(_CompiledFunc(obj1), _CompiledFunc(obj2));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(T obj)
    {
         return EqualityComparer<TKey>.Default.GetHashCode(_CompiledFunc(obj));
    }
}
```

use it like this

```
ArrayList.Sort(new Comparer2<Product, string>(p => p.Name));
```

Comment: [Simply by using `Func<T, TKey>`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1239337/2122718), but thanks for showing how to use Expresstion

Answer (score 5):

You can't pass it directly however you could do so by defining a `LambdaComparer` class that excepts a `Func<T,T,int>` and then uses that in it's `CompareTo`.

It is not quite as concise but you could make it shorter through some creative extension methods on `Func`.

Answer (score 4):

These methods don't have overloads that accept a delegate instead of an interface, but:

- You can normally return a simpler sort key through the delegate you pass to `Enumerable.OrderBy`
- Likewise, you could call `Enumerable.Select` before calling `Enumerable.SequenceEqual`
- It should be straightforward to write a wrapper that implements `IEqualityComparer<T>` in terms of `Func<T, T, bool>`
- F# lets you implement this sort of interface in terms of a lambda :)

Answer (score 3):

I vote for the dreaming theory.

You can't pass a function where an object is expected: derivatives of System.Delegate (which is what lambdas are) don't implement those interfaces.

What you probably saw is a use of the of the [`Converter<TInput, TOutput>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kt456a2y.aspx) delegate, which can be modeled by a lambda. [Array.ConvertAll](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/exc45z53.aspx) uses an instance of this delegate.

Answer (score 3):

In case if you need this function for use with lambda and possibly two different element types:

```
static class IEnumerableExtensions
{
    public static bool SequenceEqual<T1, T2>(this IEnumerable<T1> first, IEnumerable<T2> second, Func<T1, T2, bool> comparer)
    {
        if (first == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("first");

        if (second == null)
            throw new NullReferenceException("second");

        using (IEnumerator<T1> e1 = first.GetEnumerator())
        using (IEnumerator<T2> e2 = second.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (e1.MoveNext())
            {
                if (!(e2.MoveNext() && comparer(e1.Current, e2.Current)))
                    return false;
            }

            if (e2.MoveNext())
                return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
}
```