# Is Dictionary broken or should GetHashCode() only base on immutable members?

Tags: c#, .net, dictionary, immutability, hashcode

When an object is added to the .NET [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) class the hashcode of the key is stored internally and used for later comparisons.  When the hashcode changes after its initial insertion into the dictionary it often becomes "inaccessible" and may surprise its users when an existence check, even using the same reference, returns false (sample code below).

The [GetHashCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx) documentation says:

> The GetHashCode method for an object must consistently return the same hash code as long as there is no modification to the object state that determines the return value of the object's Equals method.

So, according to the `GetHashCode` docs, the hashcode may change whenever [equality](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)-determining state is changed, yet the `Dictionary` implementation does not support this.

Is the current .NET dictionary implementation broken in that it incorrectly ignore the hashcode allowances? Should `GetHashCode()` only be based on immutable members? Or, is there something else to break a possible false dichotomy?

```
class Hashable
{
    public int PK { get; set; }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        if (PK != 0) return PK.GetHashCode();
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return Equals(obj as Hashable);
    }

    public virtual bool Equals(Hashable other)
    {
        if (other == null) return false;
        else if (ReferenceEquals(this, other)) return true;
        else if (PK != 0 && other.PK != 0) return Equals(PK, other.PK);
        return false;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Hashable {0}", PK);
    }
}

class Test
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var dict = new Dictionary<Hashable, bool>();
        var h = new Hashable();
        dict.Add(h, true);

        h.PK = 42;
        if (!dict.ContainsKey(h)) // returns false, despite same reference
            dict.Add(h, false);
    }
}
```

Comment: If a Dictionary would support mutating keys, it'd have to hook into the keys and somehow get notified whenever a GetHashCode() changes. The implication of doing that sounds huge, probably just plain impossible.

Comment: I always assumed the dictionary was based on something like an underlying object id or pointer (which I'm not yet sure .NET has), but you're right - HashCode is a perfect implementation choice for a dictionary.

Comment: In fact, this design is to *allow* you to use more complex types as keys; you just need to design them properly. (If it used an object pointer, for example, you could end up with duplicates in your dictionary due to having two instances of a complex type as keys, even though you properly designed that complex type to represent, e.g., a composite key).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

No, you just shouldn't mutate a key (in a material way) after inserting it into a dictionary. This is by design, and the way that every hash table I've ever used works. The docs even specify this:

> As long as an object is used as a key in the `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>`, it must not change in any way that affects its hash value. Every key in a `Dictionary<TKey, TValue>` must be unique according to the dictionary's equality comparer. A key cannot be null, but a value can be, if the value type TValue is a reference type.

So it's only going to surprise users who don't read documentation :)

Comment: Ok, I deserved that slap in the face... and will read *all* the docs next time :).

Comment: As a silly side effect, you can mutate the object all you want, as long as the hash code is not changed (e.g. the hash code depends only on the key of an entity, not on it's values)

Comment: Jon, thank you so much for `you just shouldn't mutate a key ..`. I've read too many arguments about putting mutable objects in to dictionary keys, and what this implies for the "correct" implementation of `Equals`. When the real answer is what you just said: don't mutate keys...

Answer (score 9):

To add to Jon's answer, I would just add emphasis to a certain part of the docs that you quoted:

> The GetHashCode method for an object
>   must consistently return the same hash
>   code as long as there is no
>   modification to the object state
>   **that determines the return value of the object's Equals method**.

Now, right there you've broken the rules. You changed `PK`, which *doesn't* affect the outcome of `Equals` (because you have that `ReferenceEquals` check in there), but the result of your `GetHashCode` *does* change. So that's the simple answer.

Taking the more conceptual approach, I think you can look at it like this: if you have *overridden* the `Equals` and `GetHashCode` behavior for your type, then you've taken ownership of the concept of *what it means for one instance of this type to be equal to another*. And in fact you have defined it in a way that a `Hashable` object can be changed *into something completely different*; i.e., something that is no longer usable in the same way it was previously (because its hash code has changed).

Considered from this perspective, after you do `dict.Add(h, true)`, and then you change `h.PK`, the dictionary **doesn't** contain the object referenced by `h` anymore. It contains something *else* (which doesn't really exist anywhere). It's kind of like the type you've defined is a snake that has shed its skin.

Comment: I think you just overcomplicate things and people hardly understand what you actually wrote here. Jon Skeet said it all.

Comment: @Al: Haha... sorry? I thought I was saying something meaningful; if you feel this answer's nonsensical or overly confusing, you are free to downvote it; I won't take it personally. Although I *would* appreciate an explanation of what the really problematic part is, if possible (i.e., what specifically I said that prompted you to write that comment). Maybe I just worded myself poorly and could be clearer.

Comment: I like your paragraph that starts with "Taking the more conceptual approach". I don't really like the quoted part of the spec, since I don't see any legitimate basis for a class with visible mutable state to override `Object.Equals`. The concept of equivalence is well defined for objects of all types (class and struct); objects should override `Object.Equals` to test equivalence (even though some types (e.g. `Decimal`) override `Object.Equals` to mean something else), and `Object.GetHashCode()` should be compatible with `Object.Equals`.