# Implementing IEqualityComparer<T> on an object with two properties in C#

Tags: c#, linq, distinct, iequalitycomparer

I have a case where I need to grab a bunch of items on distinct, but my source is a collection of objects with two properties, like this:

```
public class SkillRequirement
{
    public string Skill { get; set; }
    public string Requirement { get; set; }
}
```

I try to get a collection as follows:

```
SkillRequirementComparer sCom = new SkillRequirementComparer();

var distinct_list = source.Distinct(sCom);
```

I tried to implement an `IEqualityComparer<T>` for this, but I fell stumped at the `GetHashCode()` method.

The class for the Comparer:

```
public class SkillRequirementComparer : IEqualityComparer<SkillRequirement>
{
    public bool Equals(SkillRequirement x, SkillRequirement y)
    {
        if (x.Skill.Equals(y.Skill) && x.Requirement.Equals(y.Requirement))
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public int GetHashCode(SkillRequirement obj)
    {
        //?????
    }
}
```

Normally I would just use `GetHashCode()` on a property, but because I am comparing on two properties, I'm a bit at a loss of what to do. Am I doing anything wrong, or missing something really obvious?

Comment: Be careful when using a `GetHashCode()` that's derived from mutable fields! If you put the object in a hashing collection then change one of the fields - ouch. I suggest making it immutable.

Comment: The values for the properties are orginally from a database, where the columns do not allow nulls, there are also checks for null or empty strings before an object is added to the source list, so it is not a concern :^)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can implement `GetHashCode` in the following way:

```
public int GetHashCode(SkillRequirement obj)
{
    unchecked
    {
        int hash = 17;
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.Skill.GetHashCode();
        hash = hash * 23 + obj.Requirement.GetHashCode();
        return hash;
    }
}
```

<sub>[originally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/284240) from J.Skeet</sub>

If the properties can be `null` you should avoid a `NullReferenceException`, e.g.:

```
int hash = 17;
hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Skill ?? "").GetHashCode();
hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Requirement ?? "").GetHashCode();
return hash;
```

Comment: (Actually it's originally from Josh Bloch ;)

Comment: @TimSchmelter I guess he's worried about mutating the fields after the object's been placed in a hashing container.

Comment: Wow, thanks! Do you know how it works? I never even encountered the `unchecked` keyword before... :^)

Comment: @FelixWeir: `GetHashCode` should be fast and it should not give too many collisions(equal hashcode for unequal objects). Note that `Equals` is called for every object with the same hashcode. So `Equals` must be implemented in a way that guarantees that it returns `true` for two equal objects according to the definition and vice-versa. `GetHashCode` should be implemented as efficient as possible and fairly accurate. Because checking for overflow takes time, the use of unchecked code in situations where there is no danger of overflow might improve performance.

Comment: @FelixWeir: Note that it's ok if `GetHashCode` returns the same hashcode for two different objects. You should minimize those "false hashcodes" but there's nothing wrong with it. That's why `Equals` exist as additional check. However, two equal objects should always return the same hashcode. Read: [Guidelines and rules for GetHashCode](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/02/28/guidelines-and-rules-for-gethashcode.aspx).

Comment: @TimSchmelter Distinct() implementation seems to use a hashing container.

Answer (score 1):

I would like to link the following stack overflow posts too though the question is already answered..

**GetHashCode** -

[Why is it important to override GetHashCode when Equals method is overridden?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/371328/why-is-it-important-to-override-gethashcode-when-equals-method-is-overridden)

Also, in the above answer Tim Schmelter says `the properties can be null you should avoid a NullReferenceException`

```
int hash = 17;
hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Skill ?? "").GetHashCode();
hash = hash * 23 + (obj.Requirement ?? "").GetHashCode();
return hash;
```

**IEqualityComparer** -

1. [What is the difference between using IEqualityComparer and Equals/GethashCode Override](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17137213/what-is-the-difference-between-using-iequalitycomparer-and-equals-gethashcode-ov)
2. [What's the role of GetHashCode in the IEqualityComparer in .NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4095395/whats-the-role-of-gethashcode-in-the-iequalitycomparert-in-net?rq=1)
3. [How and when to use IEqualityComparer in C#](http://www.dotnetfunda.com/blogs/sksingh/1851/how-and-when-to-use-iequalitycomparer-in-csharp)

**IEquatable** - [What's the difference between IEquatable and just overriding Object.Equals()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2734914/whats-the-difference-between-iequatable-and-just-overriding-object-equals)

**Equals** - [Guidelines for Overloading Equals()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173147(v=vs.80).aspx)

```
class TwoDPoint : System.Object
{
    public readonly int x, y;

    public TwoDPoint(int x, int y)  //constructor
    {
        this.x = x;
        this.y = y;
    }

    public override bool Equals(System.Object obj)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false.
        if (obj == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // If parameter cannot be cast to Point return false.
        TwoDPoint p = obj as TwoDPoint;
        if ((System.Object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
    }

    public bool Equals(TwoDPoint p)
    {
        // If parameter is null return false:
        if ((object)p == null)
        {
            return false;
        }

        // Return true if the fields match:
        return (x == p.x) && (y == p.y);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        //return x ^ y;
    }
}
```