# linq - return common items from n number of lists

Tags: c#, linq

I'm writing a simple search page for our intranet application. When a user searches for n words I create n lists of hits and then want to return only the results that are common to all lists.

I have something working using `List<int>` thus:

```
var list1 = new List<int> {1,2,3,4,5,8,10};
var list2 = new List<int> {3,5,6,9,10,11};
var list3 = new List<int> {3,4,5,10};

var listOfLists = new List<List<int>>{list1,list2,list3};

var results = listOfLists.Aggregate((prevList, nextList) => prevList
                 .Intersect(nextList)
                 .ToList()); 

results.Dump(); //correctly returns 3,5,10, which are common to all lists
```

However if I try this with my SearchResults class I get no results. Here's the code:

```
//results from first search word "howard"
List<SearchResult> list1 = new List<SearchResult>();
list1.Add(new SearchResult ("a.html","howard kent"));
list1.Add(new SearchResult ("b.html","howard shaw")); //the common item
list1.Add(new SearchResult ("c.html","howard smith"));
list1.Add(new SearchResult ("d.html","howard moore"));

//results from second search word "shaw"
List<SearchResult> list2 = new List<SearchResult>();
list2.Add(new SearchResult ("e.html","jon shaw"));
list2.Add(new SearchResult ("b.html","howard shaw")); //the common item
list2.Add(new SearchResult ("f.html","chris shaw"));

//could be n further lists...

//make a list of lists
List<List<SearchResult>> searchLists = new List<List<SearchResult>>();
searchLists.Add(list1);
searchLists.Add(list2);

//find results that are common to all lists.
//Doesn't work - returns nil items, should return 1
var results = searchLists
             .Aggregate((prevList, nextList) => prevList
             .Intersect(nextList)
             .ToList()); 

results.Dump();

}

class SearchResult
{
    public string Url{get;set;}
    public string SearchText { get; set; }

//constructor
public SearchResult(string url,string searchText)
{
    Url = url;
 SearchText = searchText;
}
```

How should I change the query to return the result I want?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's because the `SearchResult` objects are not the same objects, although they have the same data. You can fix this by implementing the `IEquatable<T>` interface. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131187(v=vs.110).aspx

Ie.

```
public class SearchResult : IEquatable<SearchResult>
{
    public string Url{get;set;}
    public string SearchText { get; set; }
    public bool Equals(SearchResult other)
    {
        if (other == null)
            return false;
        return string.Concat(this.Url, this.SearchText).Equals(string.Concat(other.Url, other.SearchText), StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase);
    }
}
```

Another solution would be to implement a `IEqualityComparer<T>` and pass it on to the Enumerable.Intersect method.

Comment: What's the "string.Contact(.." here?

Comment: @HowardShaw Thanks! Should ofc be string.Concat. That happens when I try to write without any editor at all.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Enumberable.Intersect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) to get the common items. But in your case you are comparing two object. So you need to implement the [IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Interface and create your own comparer class.

I am assuming your `SearchResult` class like this

```
public class SearchResult
    {
        public SearchResult(string first, string second)
        {
            First = first;
            Second = second;
        }

        public string First { get; set; }
        public string Second { get; set; }

    }
```

Now the `IEqualityComparer` interface implementation.

```
 public class MyCompare : IEqualityComparer<SearchResult>
    {
        public bool Equals(SearchResult x, SearchResult y)
        {
            return (x.First == y.First) && ((x.Second == y.Second));
        }


        public int GetHashCode(SearchResult obj)
        {
            unchecked
            {
                int hash = 17;
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.First.GetHashCode();
                hash = hash * 23 + obj.Second.GetHashCode();
                return hash;
            }
        }
}
```

The important point is within the `GetHashCode` where we need to incorporate both the properties instead of one. If we were comparing single property then it would be simple like this

```
return obj.A.GetHashCode();
```

But here we are comparing multiple properties.So that we need to change its implementation. Thanks to @Tim to their [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16667699/implementing-iequalitycomparert-on-an-object-with-two-properties-in-c-sharp)

Now you can use the Intersect method to get the common items like this

```
var common = list1.Intersect<SearchResult>(list2,new MyCompare()).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Sachin, isn't the last query just comparing two lists - I don't know how many list I might have - it will depend on how many search terms the user enters.

Comment: Yes @HowardShaw it will depend on your implementation that when should two object called as same (means which are the properties should be equal to be a common object.)