# Filter List<objet1> by using another List<objet2>

Tags: c#, linq

Sorry to Post this stupid question but I do need some help from you
I have two lists in c#. Let's call them `list<objet1> listObjet1` and `list<objet2> listObjet2`.

Here's the question : I want to somehow filter `list<objet1>` according to some matching value in `objet2` and `objet1`

```
public class Objet1 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Libelle { get; set; }

    public string IdObjet2 { get; set; }
 }
public class Objet2 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Libelle { get; set; }

    public string IdTrain { get; set; }
 }
```

I am eager to have a `List<Objet1>` where `Objet2.Id` is equal to `Objet1.Id`, I tried these Linq

```
 List<Objet1> listObjet1= (listObjet1.Select(p => p.id).Contains(listObjet2.Select(q=>q.idObjet1)))toList(); 
 List<Objet1> listObjet1= (listObjet1.Select(p => p.id).Equal(listObjet2.Select(q=>q.idObjet1))).toList();
```

Or `Equal()` which can only return some lists I don't need like `List<int>;`.

What I need is just a `List<Objet1>`

Comment: It sounds like you want to find intersecting results? If so you can use the Linq extension method `Intersects` http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx - you can use a custom equality comparer - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355408(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: do you mean that listObject1 consists of objects where ID is contained in the list of ids in listObject2?

Comment: I have given the answer of similar question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21797337/linq-return-common-items-from-n-number-of-lists/21797382#21797382

Comment: Thanks everybody ;I used the solution of  @Dominic Kexel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for a simple `Join`:

```
var result = listObjet1.Join(listObjet2, o1 => o1.Id, o2 => o2.Id, (o1, o2) => o1).ToList();
```