# .NET Generics - Compare two lists and filter: best practice

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, list, generics

I have two generic lists of type T. Both lists contain same type, and I'd like to create a third list (or a filtered version of list 2) based on the items in list two that do not exist in List 1, based on the ID of each item.

Each list holds a "Package" object, which has an ID property.

Right now I mocked up the code using For Each loops, which I know is horrible (the Big O is constant time) so I'd like a more efficent method.

this code is in VB per project requirments, but I prefer C# - so either code sample would work for me.

```
Private Sub RemoveStockPackagesFromSelection()

    Dim p As Package
    Dim packageList As List(Of Package) = New List(Of Package)
    Dim stockPackageList As List(Of Package) = New List(Of Package)
    Dim result As List(Of Package) = New List(Of Package)

    ' Fill list with User's Packages
    For i As Integer = 0 To ListBox2.Items.Count - 1
        p = New Package
        p.Id = CInt(ListBox2.Items(i).Value)
        p.Name = ListBox2.Items(i).Text
        packageList.Add(p)
    Next

    ' Fill list with Stock Packages to compare:
    Dim ds As DataSet = DAL.GetStandardPackages()

    For Each dr As DataRow In ds.Tables(0).Rows
        p = New Package
        p.Id = CInt(dr.Item("id"))
        stockPackageList.Add(p)
    Next

    ' Do Compare and Filter
    For Each p1 As Package In packageList
        For Each p2 As Package In stockPackageList
            If Not p1.Id = p2.Id Then
                result.Add(p2)
            End If
        Next
    Next

    ' Here is our new trimmed list:
    Response.Write(result.Count)

End Sub
```

What is a nice and clean LINQ or Lamda way of doing this filtering? What is the Big O of my method and what would be the Big O of the proposed method (just to satify my curiosity).

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried your code? It doesn't work the way you describe it should.

Comment: Shawn, for a question like this you can omit the filling of the  base lists. We believe you have two lists.

Comment: There are some amazing answers here composed in an amazingly short amount of time. I love this forum. I will build a sample using IEqualityComparer and Zebi's LINQ query, as this is what mainly I was looking for, but I appricate the advise on using HashSets, Dictionaries, and the .Except() extension method. All very solid and interesting solutions. I am trying to grasp Big O (which seems to be the Hot Topic of the day in CSE), so thanks for your insight guys. Great answers...

Comment: time (and memory) complexity always was and most likely always will be a hot topic in CS.

Comment: True, algorithmic programming has always been around and always will be, regardless of what new languages emerge - Big O will always be a "hot topic". Guess that was kinda a dumb thing to say... UndoSelfDepricatingComment() :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**LINQ Except Method**

This would be the cleanest way, as suggested by Maxim and svick but requires an overridden Equals method which equals on ID or you have to provide a comparer (see svicks answer).

```
var result = stockPackageList.Except(packageList).ToList();
```

**Resources**
Many LINQ samles can be found in the msdn at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746

---

I'll leave the initial parts of my answer for reference:

Brute force way:

```
var result = stockPackageList
              .Where(x => packageList.All(package => x.Id != package.Id))
              .ToList();
```

should do the trick. You just have to translate the lambda syntax to vb.net.

This query will filter all items from `stockPackageList` which IDs are not present in all items of `packageList`.

You may invert the query:

```
var result = stockPackageList
              .Where(x => packageList.Any(package => x.Id == package.Id) == false)
              .ToList();
```

The `Any` query will return true if any item in `packageList` has a matching id. This query should run a little faster because it has not to traverse the whole collection, as `All` has to.

Using Eqality:

If your package object implements `IEquatable<Package>` you can shorten the code down to

```
var result = stockPackageList
              .Where(x => packageList.Contains(x) == false)
              .ToList();
```

Using a Hash Set:

If you want to use a hash set you can do

```
var hash = new HashSet<string>(packageList.Select(x=>x.Id));
var result = stockPackageList.Where(x => hash.Contains(x.Id) == false).ToList();
```

This saves computation time when the lists become large, as faester and Ivan Danilov pointed out.

Comment: Your LINQ skills are top notch Zebi; thanks for the solution. I'm looking forward to being able to compose lamda syntax as easily and quickly as you have here. Can you help me understand what reads in human syntax? package => x => x.Id != package.Id - I'm not familiar with double => operators in a query.

Comment: Sorry, the double => was a typo :( If you want to learn about linq try this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vcsharp/aa336746, I will edit my answer, too.

Comment: And take a look at the `Except` method, examples are provided as answers, too.

Answer (score 7):

Can't really read you VB code but if you want to get the items in l2 that not in l1 -

Her's a sample C# code

```
   public class SomeObject
    {
        public string ID { get; set; }
    }

    public class SomeObjectComparer : IEqualityComparer<SomeObject>
    {
        public bool Equals(SomeObject x, SomeObject y)
        {
            return x.ID == y.ID;
        }

        public int GetHashCode(SomeObject obj)
        {
            return obj.ID.GetHashCode();
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<SomeObject> l1, l2;
            // lists init ...

            IEqualityComparer<SomeObject> comparer = new SomeObjectComparer();

            List<SomeObject> l3 = l2.Except(l1, comparer).ToList();

        }
    }
```

Comment: Except is slow on general lists as each comparison is linear.

Comment: @Ivan `Except` uses Set operations internally

Comment: This seems like it would be the "best Practice" method - very clean, readable, and OOP-y. I will use this in my production code. Thank you much @Maxim!

Answer (score 2):

Your method has asymptotic running time of O(m*n) where m and n are the sizes of your collections.

You should strive for O(m lg n). You will of course need to search both collections, but you can build a hashset of one of them in O(n) and perform queries in O(1) on average, so you should copy one list to a hashset and traverse the second looking up values in the former.

```
    static void Sort()
    {
        List<Package> a = new List<Package>();
        List<Package> b = new List<Package>();

        Func<Package, int> idExtractor = x => x.ID;

        var hash = new HashSet<Package>(a, new IDComparer<Package, int>(idExtractor));

        a.AddRange(b.Where(x => !hash.Contains(x)));
    }

    class IDComparer<ObjectType, KeyType>
        : IEqualityComparer<ObjectType>
        where KeyType : IComparable
    {
        private Func<ObjectType, KeyType> idExtractor;

        public IDComparer(Func<ObjectType, KeyType> idExtractor)
        {
            this.idExtractor = idExtractor;
        }

        public bool Equals(ObjectType x, ObjectType y)
        {
            return idExtractor(x).Equals(idExtractor(y));
        }

        public int GetHashCode(ObjectType obj)
        {
            return idExtractor(obj).GetHashCode();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Creating a hash set is O(N), not O(N lg N).

Comment: @swick: Sorry, you are right. I was confusing trees and hashsets which I shouldn't. The case where I guess O(n lg n) is vaguely justified is if the hashset needs to resize during the build up. If the initial size isn't set correctly and the strategy is to double the size each time the capacity is exceeded you will have O(lg n) such rebuilds with additional copying of the n elements. But given that I don't know if this is the strategy in the .NET hashset I should probably just assume O(n).

Comment: this is the strategy .Net uses, but it still makes the total time complexity O(N). See [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_array).

Comment: @swick: now I feel plain stupid though also somewhat wiser. I actually did a project on amortized analysis in university explaining the exact problem.  Memory is deceptive. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Except()`:

```
result = stockpackageList.Except(PackageList).ToList();
```

This assumes `Package` has overloaded `Equals()` to compare `Id`s. If it doesn't, you have to use `IEqualityComparer`, e.g. the one from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/98033/wrap-a-delegate-in-an-iequalitycomparer/3719802#3719802):

```
result = stockpackageList.Except(PackageList, 
                                 new KeyEqualityComparer<Package, int>(p => p.Id))
                         .ToList();
```

As for time complexity, your solution doesn't work correctly, so it's complexity is irrelevant. The complexity of `Except()` is O(N+M), because it first creates a hash set from the first collection (O(N)), then tries to remove each item from the second collection (O(M)) and then returns the result.

Answer (score 0):

```
var dic = new Dictionary<string, Package>(p1.Count); // capacity here is important
foreach (var p in p1) 
    dic.Add(p.Id, p);
var result = p2.Where(p => !dic.ContainsKey(p.Id)).ToList();
```

Filling dictionary is *almost* O(n) by p1.Count. And each search is O(1). So we have something close to linear complexity.

Comment: Filling dictionary is O(N), where did this notion that it's O(N log N) came from? `Dictionary` is implemented as a hash table.

Comment: It was my guess of word 'almost' in the Add() method documentation. I checked the sources with Reflector. n log n is incorrect I have to admit, but it is not O(N) either. Depending on hash collisions count single addition could be anything from O(1) to O(N). Fixed my answer, thanks.

Comment: @Ivan, yeah, but it's not single addition that matters, it's the total time. And that's on average O(N), assuming the hash function has a uniform distribution.

Comment: To be clear: for the HashSet that initially knows how much elements will be inserted and good hash distribution it is certainly linear on average. What make me doubting is that dictionary gets filled one-by-one and have to do expensive resizes of buckets from time to time.

Comment: Note that the `ContainsKey` is also "almost" an O(1) operation

Comment: Yeah, I know this. But in `ContainsKey` it doesn't need to do resizes. So if hashes are good - it is O(1) without 'almost'.

Comment: @Ivan, yeah, but resizing works the same as with `List<T>`, that is, most additions are O(1), some of them are O(current size), but the amortized time per addition is O(1) and so the total time is O(N).

Comment: @svick OK, I did some math and now I trust you. Filling depends only on hash function quality also. If hashes is good - it is linear. Thanks for exercise :)