# LINQ join is not using Equals from provided EqualityComparer, uses GetHashCode instead

Tags: linq, join

when passing EqualityComparer as last parameter to Linq Join method it is not using Equals method of it, it for some reason is using GetHashCode to compare items.

Is it possible to make it use Equals instead?

```
        var ss = new string[] { "aa", "bb", "cc" };
        var zz = new string[] { "aa", "zz", "cc" };

        var res = ss
            .Join(zz, 
                o => o, 
                i => i, 
                (i, o) => i + o, 
                new GenericEqualityComparer<String>((x,y) => x == y))
            .ToList();
```

Comment: Do you mean it _never_ or  _not always_ uses `Equals`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When an `IEqualityComparer<T>` compares to objects, it first compares their hashcodes. Only if they are equal the `Equals` method is used to refine the comparison. So in your case it should at least hit `Equals` twice.

To demonstrate what an EqualityComparer does I made a little code snippet in Linqpad:

```
void Main()
{
    var ss = new string[] { "aa1", "bb1", "cc1" };
    var zz = new string[] { "aa2", "aa3", "zz2", "cc2" };

    var res = ss.Join(zz,  o => o, i => i, (i, o) => i + o,
        new SubstringComparer()).ToList();
}

public class SubstringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
{
    public bool Equals(string left, string right)
    {
        string.Format("{0} - {1}", left, right).Dump();
        return left.Substring(0,2) == right.Substring(0,2);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(string value)
    {
        value.Dump();
        return value.Substring(0,2).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

So strings are equal if their first two characters are equal. The output is:

> aa2
>   aa3
>   aa2 - aa3
>   zz2
>   cc2
>   aa1
>   aa2 - aa1
>   bb1
>   cc1
>   cc2 - cc1

And the resulting list:

> aa1aa2
>   aa1aa3
>   cc1cc2

You see that first the second list is compared (I'm not sure why, by the way, maybe the hashcodes are cached) and then the pairs.

So when your `GenericEqualityComparer` *never* hits `Equals` it somehow always generates a unique hashcode, which I think should be a bug. If it *not always* uses `Equals`, here is the explanation. And if you want a comparer to *always* use `Equals` you should make it always return an identical hashcode (which is inefficient, of course).

Answer (score 0):

https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719802/136967

has a very good explanation.  Basically, comparisons are done using Equals() but GetHashCode() is used by the Linq code when doing the processing and if not implemented correctly it will give strange answers.

hth, 
Alan.