# Why there is no corresponding delegate for IEqualityComparer as there is a Comparison for IComparer

Tags: c#, .net, linq, delegates

For those extension methods that receive an `IComparer` as argument, I can easily obtain the corresponding instance trough the method [Comparer.Create](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh737198%28VS.110%29.aspx) that creates an `IComparer<T>` from a `Comparison<T>`.

In the same way, it would be nice to have a corresponding delegate for the interface `IEqualityComparer`. Why it does not exist?

Comment: This is a very good question, but can probably be summed up like most of these questions. The designers of the language and framework just didn't do it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The general contract for equality is that it must behave in a way consistent with the same hash code method: that two objects which equality says are equal must report the same hash value. So you cannot provide a consistent equality implementation through a unique method.
Instead, you require a contract that includes both methods (equals and hash code) and therefore a delegate is not enough to specify that contract and you need an interface such as `IEqualityComparer` including two methods.

You can find more reasons in the following [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719802/1140754), which uses the `Distinct` method as an example.