# Comparing two lists according to specific properties

Tags: c#, linq

how can i compare 2 lists and have the not matching items but according to the specifics properties

```
public partial class Cable : StateObject
{            
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int CablePropertyId { get; set; }
    public int Item { get; set; }
    public int TagNo { get; set; }
    public string GeneralFormat { get; set; }
    public string EndString { get; set; }
    public string CableRevision { get; set; }         
}
```

I want to comparision accomplished accoring to the CablePropertyId,TagNo and CableRevision, if i use

```
var diffCables = sourceCables.Except(destinationCables).ToList();
```

the whole properties are compared to each other . how can i do that?

Comment: Have you tried overriding the Equals method?

Comment: @BSoD_ZA: That does not suffice, you need to override `Equals` + `GetHashCode` or create and use a custom `IEqualityComparer` as mentioned below.

Comment: You should check the following answer:
[Compare lists using LINQ and Join](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55138693/7606096) Works great!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Linq except method with custom EqualityComparer.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390(v=vs.110).aspx

```
class CableComparer : IEqualityComparer<Cable>
{
    public bool Equals(Cable x, Cable y)
    {
        return (x.CablePropertyId == y.CablePropertyId && ...);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(Cable x) // If you won't create a valid GetHashCode based on values you compare on, Linq won't work properly
    {
        unchecked
        {
            int hash = 17;
            hash = hash * 23 + x.CablePropertyID;
            hash = hash * 23 + ...
        }
        return hash;
    }
}

var diffCables = sourceCables.Except(destinationCables, new CableComparer());
```

Also, `ToList()` operation on the result isn't really necessary. Most of the time you can just operate on the result of Linq query `IEnumerable` without specifying the exact type; this way you won't waste performance on unneeded `ToList()` operation.

By the way, a couple of others proposed Where-based queries with simple lambda. Such solution is easier to read (in my opinion), but it's also less optimized: it forces n^2 checks, while IEqualityComparer allows Linq to be more optimal because of `GetHashCode()` method. Here's a [great answer on importance of GetHashCode](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719802/312725), and here's a [great guide on writing `GetHashCode()` override](https://stackoverflow.com/a/263416/312725).

Comment: what do you mean by  return x.CablePropertyId ...;

Comment: @nnmmss expanded this according with Jon Skeet's recommendations about `GetHashCode()` implementation for clarity.

Answer (score 1):

You can create your own [`IEqualityComparer<Cable>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132151.aspx) like this:

```
public class CableComparer : IEqualityComparer<Cable>
{
    public bool Equals(Cable x, Cable y)
    {
        return x.CablePropertyId == y.CablePropertyId &&
               x.TagNo == y.TagNo &&
               x.CableRevision == y.CableRevision;
    }

    // If Equals() returns true for a pair of objects  
    // then GetHashCode() must return the same value for these objects. 
    public int GetHashCode(Cable x)
    {
        return x.CablePropertyId ^ 
               x.TagNo.GetHashCode() ^ 
               x.CableRevision.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then use [this overload of `Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb336390.aspx):

```
var comparer = new CableComparer();
var diffCables = sourceCables.Except(destinationCables, comparer).ToList();
```

Alternatively, the [MoreLINQ library](https://code.google.com/p/morelinq/) (also [available on NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq/)) provides a convenient `ExceptBy` method:

```
var diffCables = sourceCables.ExceptBy(
        destinationCables, 
        x => new { 
            x.CablePropertyId, 
            x.TagNo,
            x.CableRevision
        })
    .ToList();
```

Comment: I don't think that bitwise xor is a good way to write `GetHashCode()`. You'll get a collision on {1,2,4} and {2,1,4}, which seems a very likely combination.

Answer (score 0):

You can override the Equals and GetHashCode methods of `Cable` if you will always compare this object in this manner.

Otherwise you can write a custom comparer and use the overload for .Except

[List.Except Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb908822%28v=vs.90%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

If you use LINQ with `IQueryable<>`, there may be solution with `Where()`

```
var destinationCablesAnon = destinationCables.Select(a=>new {a.CablePropertyId, a.TagNo ,a.CableRevision}); // add ToArray() if use IEnumerable<>

var diffCables  = sourceCables.Where(a=>!destinationCables.Contains(new {a.CablePropertyId, a.TagNo ,a.CableRevision})).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Essentially, when you want to compare your own types, you'll need to describe how they compare/differ from each other. Linq wouldn't know which properties in your `Cable` class are different right?

So you build a comparer which can be used generally to compare two types.

In this case, two `Cable` instances:

```
class CableComparer : IEqualityComparer<Cable>
{

    public bool Equals(Cable c1, Cable c2)//these represent any two cables.
    {
        if (c1.Height == c2.Height && ...)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }


    public int GetHashCode(Cable c)
    {
        //this will work if each ID is unique
        return c.Id.GetHashCode();
        //otherwise you do this:
        //return (c.Id ^ c. CablePropertyId).GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then:

```
IEnumerable<Cable> except =
            sourceCables.Except(destinationCables, new CableComparer());
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use something like this:

```
sourceCables.Where(sc => !destinationCables.Any(dc => dc.CablePropertyId == sc.CablePropertyId && ...));
```

Comment: I think that while lambda-based approach is more readable, it can be worse performance-wise, as it won't be able to use optimizations based on GetHashCode in IEqualityComparer<T>.