# c# combine lists and mark item as found

Tags: c#

I have a class:

```
public class Item
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFound { get; set; }
}
```

and 2 lists:

```
List<Item> first = new List<Item>();
List<Item> second = new List<Item>();
```

- `First` list contains some predefined unique items
- `Second` list contains also some unique items

How can I add the second list items to the first list without duplicates based on `Name` property, ignoring cases?

Comment: Create a custom comparer?

Comment: `first.SingleOrDefault(x=>x.Name=name)`? also second

Comment: Could you publish some examples ?

Comment: I'm lazy, so I would create a new list "results". Loop through the original two and then compare and add to the new collection. Far cleaner solutions can be implemented.

Comment: @TimSchmelter: The first list items should stay, of course, if the same items are in the second list do nothing, otherwise add them to the first list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add items from `second` into existing `first` list:

```
  List<Item> first = new List<Item>();
  List<Item> second = new List<Item>();
  ... 
  // ids to exclude while adding
  HashSet<String> ids = new HashSet<string>(first.Select(item => item.Name),
    StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
  // add all items from the second, except exluded 
  first.AddRange(second.Where(item => !ids.Contains(item.Name)));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
First.Union(Second).GroupBy(x=>x.Name).Select(x=>x.FirstOrDefault());
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution with `` HashSet`1 `` and `` IEquatable`1 ``.
If you need to work with `` List`1 ``s, you can use Linq as poined out in the answer by Ned Stoyanov.

**Code**:

```
class Program {
    static void Main(string[] args) {
        var first = new HashSet<Item>() {
            new Item() { Name = "a" },
            new Item() { Name = "b" },
        };
        var second = new HashSet<Item>() {
            new Item() { Name = "b" },
            new Item() { Name = "c" },
        };
        var both = first.Union(second).ToList();
        both.ForEach(Console.WriteLine);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}

public class Item : IEquatable<Item> {
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public bool IsFound { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object that) {
        return that is Item && this.Equals((Item)that);
    }

    public bool Equals(Item that) {
        return this.Name.Equals(that.Name, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase);
    }

    public override int GetHashCode() {
        return Name.GetHashCode();
    }

    public override string ToString() {
        return Name;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
a
b
c
```

*Note*: Due to the implementation of `` HashSet`1 ``s, the order of elements is not respected.

Answer (score 0):

If you know in advance that your lists have unique items, why are they not ISet< Item>? That's exactly what ISet's are for. 
Once you change them to ISets, you can simply call:

```
first.UnionWith(second);
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I add the second list items to the first list without
>   duplicates based on Name property, ignoring cases?

This does what you want:

```
List<Item> third = first.Concat(second)
    .GroupBy(i => i.Name, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)
    .Select(g => new Item
    {
        Name = g.Key,
        IsFound = g.Count() > 1
    })
    .ToList();
```

`g.Count() > 1` is true only for items with the same name(ignoring case) that came from different lists, so `g.Count()` is either 1 or 2.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement a `IEqualityComparer<Item>` or better yet, use the `KeyEqualityComparer` from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719802/1239433). You can use Linq `Union` to get your result.

```
first.Union(second, new KeyEqualityComparer( i => i.Name));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
var distinct = from item in second
               where first.All(x => !String.Equals(x.Name, item.Name, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
               select item;
first.AddRange(distinct);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can have a combined list where only missing items from second are added.

```
   class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var first = new List<Item> { new Item("one"), new Item("two") };
            var second = new List<Item> { new Item("two"), new Item("three") };
            var combined = new List<Item>();

            combined.AddRange(first);

            foreach (var item in second)
            {
                int index = combined.FindIndex(x => x.name == item.name);
                if (index <= 0)
                {
                    combined.Add(item);
                }

            }

            foreach (var item in combined)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.name);
            }

        }

        class Item
        {
            public string name;
            public Item(string name)
            {
                this.name = name;
            }
        }
    }
```