# Checking if all items in one generic collection exist in another using custom comparison delegate

Tags: c#, linq, generics, delegates

I have a situation where I need a generic method to which I can pass two collections of type T along with a delegate that compares the two collections and returns true if every element in collection 1 has an equal element in collection 2, even if they are not in the same index of the collection.  What I mean by "equal" is handled by the delegate.  My initial thought was to return false if the collections were different lengths and otherwise sort them and then compare them like parallel arrays.  Then it occurred to me that I can't sort a collection of a generic type without the types sharing an interface.  So now I am thinking a LINQ expression might do the trick, but I can't think of how to write it.  Consider my current code:

```
private static bool HasSameCollectionItems<T>(ICollection<T> left, ICollection<T> right, Func<T, T, bool> func)
{
    if (left.Count != right.Count)
    {
        return false;
    }

    foreach (var item in left)
    {
        bool leftItemIsInRightCollection = ??? MAGIC ???

        if (!leftItemIsInRightCollection)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    return true;
}
```

I would like to replace `??? MAGIC ???` with a LINQ expression to see if `item` is "equal" to an element in `right` using the passed in delegate `func`.  Is this even possible?

Note: For reasons I don't want to bother getting into here, impelemnting IEquatable or overriding the Equals method is not an option here.

Comment: And why are you looking for LINQ and MAGIC when `for` & `foreach` are right there waiting for you?

Comment: @Amit - I'm not sure exactly what you mean, but my original plan was to order the collections and then use a for loop to check the parallel elements against each other.  When I got to that point I realize "Oops, I can't order a collection of type T."

Comment: You can iterate it from the start each and every time. All you have is an equality checking function that you *have* to apply to each item, so do exactly that. (And us, it will be O(n^2))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want `.All()` and `.Any()` methods (first method checks that *all* elements satisfy condition second only check if such an element exist) :

```
bool leftItemIsInRightCollection = right.Any(rItem => func(item, rItem));
```

Also i'd refactor your code to something like :

```
    private static bool HasSameCollectionItems<T>(ICollection<T> left, ICollection<T> right, Func<T, T, bool> func)
    {
        return left.Count == right.Count && left.All(LI => right.Any(RI => func(LI, RI)));
    }
```

Comment: This works but is slow for large collections because: [O(n^2)](http://stackoverflow.com/a/487278/141397)

Comment: Yes, I believe this is perfect.  I actually have my code more like what you refactored it into but broke it out too illustrate where that magic had to happen.  I was getting lost in the weeds trying to do everything against the left object, chaining Any and Where and all kinds of stuff.  I knew a second set of eyes would help me cut through the garbage.  Thanks.

Comment: @3dGrabber Can you think of a faster way without messing with hash codes?

Comment: No.   
Unless you can sort the collections, in which case you need `IComparer<T>` or an equivalent delegate

Comment: @Fabjan - The last bit of the refactored code has the ! on func().  Isn't this backwards?  func() returns true if the objects match.  Am I getting twisted?

Comment: @bubbleking thank you, it's just a typo, corrected it

Answer (score 0):

The following works by checking whether there are element in `left` which are not in `right`.

If you insist on a delegate to determine equality, you can use the `FuncEqualityComparer` from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3719617/141397).  (Note that you must also provide an implementation for `Object.GetHashCode`)

```
private static bool HasSameCollectionItems<T>(ICollection<T> left, ICollection<T> right,  IEqualityComparer<T> comparer)
{
    if (left.Count != right.Count) return false;

    return !left.Except(right, comparer).Any();
}
```