# How to test two objects are equal in xunit.net?

Tags: unit-testing, xunit.net

I am reading [Test Driven Development: By Example](http://www.amazon.com/Test-Driven-Development-By-Example/dp/product-description/0321146530). All examples use Java and Junit (I am on chapter 10). There are one test method that test for equality of two objects. I already override Equals of the class but when run my test it failed.

This is sample code

```
public class BaseX
{
    public string Test { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        return this.Test == ((BaseX)obj).Test;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("Tyep: {0}, Test: {1}", this.GetType().Name, this.Test);
    }
}

public class A : BaseX
{

}
```

This is my test code

```
[Fact]
public void FunTest2()
{
    var b1 = new BaseX();
    var a1 = new A();

    b1.Test = "a";
    a1.Test = "a";

    Assert.Equal(a1, b1);
}
```

When I run the test, it will failed with this message.

```
TDD1.UnitTest.UnitTest1.FunTest2 : Assert.Equal() Failure
Expected: Tyep: A, Test: a
Actual:   Tyep: BaseX, Test: a
```

I think `Assert.Equal` compare both value and type of objects. So, I looked on xunit code and found that `Assert.Equal` call `IEqualityComparer.Equals`. If I want to compare two object with override method, what method should I use?

**Update**
I test this on **Windows 7**, **Visual Studio 11 Beta**, **xunit.net 1.9.0.1566** (get files from nuget)

Comment: `Test` is protected so how is it that you are able to say `var b1.Text = "a";` in the test? In any case, if you made `Test` public and then ran the code you supplied in this question, it passes when I try it.

Comment: I just updated my code and also added information about my machine. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Before comparing both objects using T's Equals method, xunit compares types:

```
// Same type?
if (!skipTypeCheck && x.GetType() != y.GetType())
    return false;
```

As I see it, you have two choices:

**The simple choice**

```
Assert.True(b1.Equals(a1));
```

It might be less expected than an Equal overload, but KISS...

**The less simple choice**

```
public class BaseXComparer : IEqualityComparer<BaseX>
{
    public bool Equals(BaseX x, BaseX y)
    {
        return x.Test.Equals(y.Test);
    }

    public int GetHashCode(BaseX obj)
    {
        return obj.Test.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

And then:

```
Assert.Equal(a1, b1, new BaseXComparer());
```

In this case, consider [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74032/whats-the-recommended-best-practice-for-using-iequalitycomparert).

Until someone will add a new overload (shouldn't be tricky, as the inner implementation has a bool parameter for this) or an extension, I'd recommend using the simple method above.

Comment: For me it worked by implementing IEquatable<BaseX>; xUnit is compliant with this interface.